# Variables I defined in Module are not evaluated as I expected

Tags: functions, scoping

I want to make and use object like stuff of Object-Oriented Programming language(like JavaScript) in Mathematica and am trying it by referring to [the answer of this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13360/do-objects-in-mathematica-have-to-be-declared) using `Module`.

For example, I want to make an object(Module) which has the following properties and Methods:

Properties:

- a : 2 (integer)
- b : 4^a
- f : func[a], with `func: function which just returns an argument doing nothing else. (func : x -> x)`
- c = 4^f

Methods:

- showA: returns a
- showB: returns b
- showC: returns c

I wrote a code below, but the result was not what I had expected:

```
In[529]:= func[x_] := (
  Return[x]
  )

foo = Module[
   {
    a = 2,
    b = 4^a,
    f = func[a],
    c = 4^f
    },
   Switch[#,
     "showA", a,
     "showB", b,
     "showC", c
     ]
    &];
foo["showA"]
foo["showB"]
foo["showC"]

Out[531]= 2

Out[532]= 1048576 //expected output: 16

Out[533]= 4^f //expected output :16
```

What is wrong?
If it is impossible to do, what is the alternative simplest way to achieve this?

Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: the bound variables in module can't refer to each other within the first argument; so, `Module[{a = 3, b = 4 a}, f[a,b]]` would give `f[3, 4a]`, because the `a` on the rhs of `b = 4 a` is not the "module version" of `a`, but the external `a`. (You can notice this from the syntax highlighting—it's blue, not green.)

Comment: Also, i'm not sure `func[x_] := (Return[x])` means what you might think it means! `Return` is only used for control flow changes in mathematica, like breaking out of `For` loops or sequential evaluation (`;`). You'll still get the expected output from `func` in this case, but you may as well use `func[x_] := x`.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know  {} inside Module refers only to external variables.

Comment: The reason I used `Return` instead of writing `func[x_] := x` is just I wanted to know whether it works as a "return" keyword of other ordinary programming languages. The 
function I need in my actual project requires much more to do than `func[x_] := x` (including For loop calculation) and 
I thought I needed to use `Return` for returning the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is the most minimal re-writing of the OP that I could come up with

```
func[x_] := x
foo = Module[{a = 2},
   b = 4^a;
   f = func[a];
   c = 4^f;
   Switch[#, "showA", a, "showB", b, "showC", c] &];
foo["showA"]
foo["showB"]
foo["showC"]
```

and gives the following as output

```
2
16
16
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thank you. It worked.  I didn't know {} inside Module refers only to external variables.

Comment: But `b`, `f`, & `c` are now global. I would declare them in the module header, but assign values in the body.

Comment: sorry, maybe I misunderstood what you meant earlier. Just to be clear, do you need all variables to be defined in the Module?

Comment: Yes, it is preferable to trap variables in the Module for not coming upto global scope.