# What's fastest way of defining 10^5 down values?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, map

I want to define

```
isGood[___] = False;

isGood[#] = True & /@ list
```

where `list` is a list of several million integers.   What's the fastest way of doing this?

Comment: I'd use `Scan[]` instead of `Map[]`, for starters... is there no regular pattern to these "several million integers" that can possibly be exploited?

Comment: Those numbers have no pattern.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Summary: undocumented `HashTable` is a bit faster (at least in version 9) both in storage and in retrieval than `DownValues`.

### DownValues

```
list = RandomInteger[{-10^9, 10^9}, 10^6];
ret  = RandomInteger[{-10^9, 10^9}, 10^6];

isGood[___] = False;
Scan[(isGood[#] = True) &, list]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {3.240005, Null} *)

ClearAll[isGood];
isGood[___] = False;
Do[isGood@i = True, {i, list}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {2.350003, Null} *)
```

On my computer, this takes less then 3 seconds for a million integers if `Do` is used instead of `Scan`. Isn't this fast enough?

Retrieval of the results is also quite quick, and is almost independent whether `Table` or `Map` is used:

```
isGood /@ ret; // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {1.410002, Null} *)

Table[isGood@i, {i, ret}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {1.450002, Null} *)
```

### HashTable

Out of curiosity, I compared this to the undocumented `HashTable` (mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1029/745)) and got even better results. Note, that the hash table must be checked for existing value (as `list` might contain duplicates) otherwise `HashTableAdd` returns with error. Or it is even better to prefilter `list` by removing duplicates, but that is omitted here not to bias the comparison.

```
hash = System`Utilities`HashTable[];
Do[If[
    Not@System`Utilities`HashTableContainsQ[hash, i], 
    System`Utilities`HashTableAdd[hash, i, True] (* last argument can be omitted *)
    ], {i, list}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {2.010003, Null} *)

System`Utilities`HashTableContainsQ[hash, #] & /@ ret; // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {1.340002, Null} *)

Table[System`Utilities`HashTableContainsQ[hash, i], {i, ret}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {1.050001, Null} *)
```

We see that both storage and retrieval are a bit faster.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my edit: I did justice to`HashTable`. I wonder why it was so slow (~27 sec) in your original example. `Table` is obviously faster than `Scan` & `With`, but I also assume that in version 8 `HashTable` did not throw an error when encountering a duplicate hash, but silently failed with a slowdown.

Comment: I also expect version 10 [associations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Associations.html) to be at the performance level of `HashTable`, but that will need another post.

Answer (score 12):

Are you sure you want to use `UpValues`? You can use `Dispatch` which is pretty fast when generating the lookup table and is equally fast when accessing values:

```
n = 6;
list = RandomInteger[{0, 10^(n + 1)}, {10^n}];

AbsoluteTiming[disp = Dispatch@Thread[list -> True];]
```

> ```
> {1.6220927, Null}
> ```

```
Remove[isGood];
AbsoluteTiming[isGood[___] = False; Scan[(isGood[#] = True) &, list]]
```

> ```
> {3.5982058, Null}
> ```

Query values:

```
test = RandomInteger[{0, 10^(n + 1)}, {10^n}];

AbsoluteTiming[Count[test /. disp, True]]
```

> ```
> {1.9151096, 94844}
> ```

```
AbsoluteTiming[Count[isGood /@ test, True]]
```

> ```
> {1.7601007, 94844}
> ```

Comment: In this case he wants to use DownValues not UpValues.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be faster to define downvalues

```
list = RandomInteger[{-100000000, 100000000}, 1000000];
DownValues[isGood] = 
   HoldPattern[isGood[#]] :> True & /@ list; // AbsoluteTiming
isGood[___] = False;
```

Comment: Again, `Scan[]` would be preferable to using `Map[]` in this case...

Comment: @J.M., I'm saving all downvalues at once

Answer (score 6):

My solution is ugly, but task-specific. It builds a bitmap out of machine-sized integers in imperative fashion and uses Compile. This works reasonably in memory usage for ranges that have at least couple percent of True values.

A million integers:

```
n = 6;
list = RandomInteger[{0, 10^(n + 1)}, {10^n}];
```

Function itself:

```
<< Developer`

isGood = With[
     {bits = Floor[Log[2, $MaxMachineInteger + 1]],
      min = Min@list,
      max = Max@list},
     With[
      {bv = Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}},
          Module[
           {bitvec = Table[0, {(max - min + bits - 1)~Quotient~bits}]},
           Scan[(bitvec[[(# - min)~Quotient~bits + 1]] += 
               2^((# - min)~Mod~bits)) &, Union@list];
           bitvec
           ],
          CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
            "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}
          ]@list},
      Compile[{{x, _Integer}},
       min <= x <= max && 
          bv[[(x - min)~Quotient~bits + 1]]~BitAnd~(2^((x - min)~Mod~bits)) != 0,
       CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True, 
         "InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}
       ]
      ]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

(* 0.347843 *)
```

Usage:

```
isGood /@ list // AbsoluteTiming // First

(* 0.590347 *)
```

Originally I wanted to solve this problem using bitwise operations of arbitrarily large integers, but the issue with that is that functional programming with bigints has large return value overheads - even when just some individual bits are twiddled.

Comment: A few possible tweaks: use `bits = BitLength[$MaxMachineInteger]` to compute the maximum bit length, and you can use `bitvec = ConstantArray[0, Quotient[max - min + bits - 1, bits]]` for initialization.

Answer (score 3):

What you aim at can be done quicker now with `Association`. I compare only to the `Do` method, which is also reasonably fast:

```
list = RandomInteger[{-10^9, 10^9}, 10^6];
ret = RandomInteger[{-10^9, 10^9}, 10^6];
ClearAll[isGood];
isGood[___] = False;
Do[isGood@i = True, {i, list}]; // AbsoluteTiming
isAlsoGood = With[{data = Union[list]},
    AssociationThread[data -> ConstantArray[True, Length[data]]]
]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* 1.43326 *)
(* 0.673688 *)
```

And looking up values is even four times faster:

```
aa = Map[isGood, ret]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
bb = Lookup[isAlsoGood, ret, False]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
aa == bb

(* 0.959888 *)
(* 0.2606 *)
(* True *)
```

Even *deallocation* is considerably faster:

```
ClearAll[isGood]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
ClearAll[isAlsoGood]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

(* 0.656773 *)
(* 0.279496 *)
```

Comment: Note that Boolean arrays cannot be packed. Only integer, real and complex arrays can be packed.

Comment: @CarlWoll Yes I know. This `ToPackedArrayQ` was what remained from may experiments with `Boolean`. I removed it.