# How to efficiently take complement of two big lists?

Tags: list-manipulation, memory

I have a giant list `l1` and some smaller lists `l21`, `l21`, ..., `l2n`.  The `l1` is the superset and has $\tilde{}10^7$ elements.  `l2?` is subset of `l1` (if my other code does correct job).   All lists only contain numbers (again, if my code does correct job).    I need to take complement of `l1` and each of the `l2?`.   The number of subsets (i.e. `n`) is several hundreds.   What's the most memory/time efficient way of doing this?  I run this on 4GB machine and usually have 1.* GB of free memory when the program reaches that stage.  I'd probably save numbers in file and use some command-line tool like `grep` to do this.  But the original lists are all prepared in a Mathematica program.  If there is a good solution in Mathematica then i'd like to avoid going out.

Comment: You've tried `Complement[]` already?

Comment: If your lists of integers are reasonably dense and entries are non-repeating, you can use arbitrary-length integers interpreted as bit vectors as representation of these lists. These integers can be constructed using repetitive `BitSet`, complement performed using `BitAnd[l1,BitNot[l2?]]`, and values collected through `BitGet`. This is elegant, but slow. For a faster kludge, see [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13708/3056]. Both methods consume roughly one bit (not byte) per integer (present or not in the list) in list range. (I believe `Complement` should be sufficient though.)

Comment: Small addition: unless you create the lists in special fashion from the start, you don't really get space benefit over `Complement` in the large scheme of things. If you had billions of integers, optimization could make sense, but otherwise...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends.. How many numbers are in the subsets? In which range are you numbers? What do you want to do with each complement? Can you give a small example using `RandomInteger` to create sample-data? Generally, you could first try to calculate one complement by using something like this

```
l1 = RandomInteger[{0, 10^6}, {10^7}];
l21 = RandomInteger[{0, 10^6}, {10^5}];

compl = Complement[l1, l21];
```

and see whether you memory is sufficient.

To see how much memory is used you can try`MemoryInUse[]`. `ByteCount[expr]` is able to find out how much memory is used by a variable (or expression in general). After the above command, I have wasted

```
MemoryInUse[]/2^20.

(* Out[9]= 101.952 *)
```

about 100 MB here.