# What is the point of Refresh if Dynamic has an UpdateInterval option?

Tags: front-end, dynamic, function-comparison

I haven't found an example where I can't get rid of Refresh[]:

```
In[1]:= Dynamic[DateString[],UpdateInterval->1]
Out[1]= Sat 10 Nov 2012 01:36:34
In[2]:= Dynamic[Refresh[DateString[],UpdateInterval->1]]
Out[2]= Sat 10 Nov 2012 01:36:34
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let me know if this is not enough, but I'll just quote the docs for now

From the [Advanced Dynamic Functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html) tutorial:

> #### Nesting Refresh
>
> In the "Refresh" section examples, `Refresh` is always the outermost
>   function inside `Dynamic`. You might almost wonder why its options are
>   not simply options to `Dynamic`. But in fact it is often important to
>   place `Refresh` as deeply in the expression as possible, especially if
>   it specifies a time-based updating interval.
>
> Consider this example.
>
> ```
> DynamicModule[{showclock = True}, {Checkbox[Dynamic[showclock]], 
>   Dynamic[If[showclock, Refresh[DateList[], UpdateInterval -> 0.05], 
>     "No clock"]]}]
> ```
>
> When the checkbox is checked, `Refresh` is causing frequent updating of
>   the clock, and CPU time is being consumed to keep things up-to-date.
>   When the checkbox is unchecked, however, the Refresh expression is no
>   longer reached by evaluation, the output remains static, and no CPU
>   time is consumed. If `Refresh` were wrapped around the whole expression
>   inside `Dynamic`, CPU time would be consumed constantly, even if the
>   clock were not being displayed. The words "No clock" would be
>   constantly refreshed, pointlessly. (This refreshing is not visible;
>   there is no flicker of the screen, but CPU time is being consumed
>   nevertheless.)

Comment: So what's the difference and why just not use Dynamic instead of Refresh?

Comment: @Kuba They are VERY different. Refresh evaluates to nothing, it's just a marker that means "if you get to evaluate this snippet when updating the dynamic, then remember these are the update settings I want". Dynamic is something that doesn't evaluate at all, and it means "if this is going to be displayed in the front end, evaluate the contents before showing trying to reevaluate every time the user is looking at it and the result would change"

Comment: But where's the difference if in the example above you replace Refresh with Dynamic? I know Refresh alone has no point but why to nest Refresh if you just may nest Dynamics? God, sometimes I think I should switch to cycling.

Comment: @Kuba, its a case where you won't see a visual difference but its just a special case. It's not just that Refresh alone has no point. Its that Refresh doesn't affect calculations, its more like a tag, while Dynamic isn't evaluated. For example, if you changed `Refresh[DateList[]` to `100 Refresh[DateList[]`, then it would be different to `100 Dynamic[DateList[]`. The `Dynamic` has to make sense as a visual piece of thing on the screen.

Comment: I'm back! If you put `Print["check"]; showclock` in `If` you can see that whole `Dynamic` is evaluated, so `UpdateInterval` setting from refresh is passed to outer `Dynamic`. IMO this example sucks, using nested `Dynamic` would be way better habit to learn because the If statement would be only checked when showclock is changed, not each .05 second

Answer (score 14):

I really think that other answers here are adequate, but since specific examples are being requested, here's one.

```
f[x_] := memoize[x]
memoize[x_]:=memoize[x]=x
```

This is a function you want to call inside and outside of `Dynamic`.  You want the caching effect, but you don't want `Dynamic` to go crazy on this.  Which it will.  Observe:

```
In[139]:= Clear[memoize];
f[x_] := memoize[x]
memoize[x_]:=memoize[x]=x
counter=0;
Dynamic[Refresh[counter++,None];f[20]]
Dynamic[counter]

Out[142]= 20 (* the on-screen representation of memoize[20] *)
Out[143]= 2 (* the on-screen representation of counter *)
```

I'm using `counter` here as an indication of how many times the `memoize` `Dynamic` resolves itself.

So, this `Dynamic` evaluated twice.  Rather ironic given that I was actually trying to *save* computational power by memoizing.  But we're not done, yet.  Evaluate:

```
f[40]
```

Note `counter` just ticked again.  And, no, putting `Dynamic` inside of the definition of `f` does not work.  Because we don't want `f` to produce a `Dynamic`.  We want a value, not a `Dynamic`.  So, delete your previous outputs (else they'll continue to trigger and contaminate the experiment) and redefine `f` as:

```
f[x_] := Refresh[memoize[x], None]
```

Problem solved.  I write real-world functions which create caches in this way.  I do not want them triggering wildly inside of `Dynamic`.

Comment: I have used an explicit `TrackedSymbol:>{f}` option for the `Dynamic[Refresh[counter++,None];f[20]]` in such cases which seems to achieve the same behavior. Can you explain what the advantage of the `Refresh` approach is? I find it somewhat problematic that the author of `f` has to take care of a `Dynamic` not refreshing which might make use of `f` which he probably not even knows about when he originally wrote `f` (hasn't that situation occured at WRI?). What is the overhead of such a `Refresh`, would you recommend to generally use such `Refresh` wrappers just in case of?

Comment: @AlbertRetey the overhead is about 25%. Check: `RepeatedTiming[Do[ Refresh[i^2, None], {i, 10^6}]][[1]]/RepeatedTiming[Do[ unfresh[i^2, None], {i, 10^6}]][[1]]` Maybe this explains the slowdown of 15-30% in pure kernel operations from Mathematica 9 to Mathematica 10 ?

Comment: @AlbertRetey, I'm talking about a situation where a developer is making `f` available for your use by users. If I don't have end-to-end control, then I have to anticipate any usage. It's not reasonable for me to tell users to hack around my problems. That having been said, this certainly does not arise in many functions. Functions developed with no side effects (which is quite a lot of them) won't exhibit this behavior. For example, in 10.0.0, there was an infinite `Dynamic` triggering bug in `GeoGraphics`. The solution finding the accidental side effects and removing them, not `Refresh`.

Comment: @RolfMertig, `Refresh` is not widely deployed in v10. It is deployed where necessary.  Your speculation about widespread slowdowns, if warranted generally, is not applicable to a connection with `Refresh` specifically (particularly since v10 has nothing new in regards to `Dynamic`).

Comment: @JohnFultz Thank's for the clarification. Though I am still confused as to why a kernel-only function should ever worry about the FrontEnd. I just do not use this design pattern and still can use kernel memoization just fine.

Comment: @JohnFultz: Am I correctly understanding that whenever you can't avoid side effects in a function (which one of course should avoid where possible) AND you expect it to be used in `Dynamic` then you would recommend to use a `Refresh` in such a function as shown? Is the developer/user responsibility really the only relevant difference between my `TrackedSymbols` approach?

Comment: @AlbertRetey I think I got this example and if so better names would help future readers. Like: `memoize`->`myThemePlotWithHeavyComputation` and `f`->`tabPlotsFromMainTabView`, where the former is the Kernel function that, what was my concern too, doesn't have to be wrapped in `Refresh` "just in case". However the latter is specific package symbol related to package GUI where `Refresh` makes sense, it would be there because of specific reason, not just in case.

Comment: @AlbertRetey Moreover you can export/share Kernel functions `memoize` and friends with others without worrying about useless (harming) `Refresh`es hanging around. At least, this is what I got from the answer. Abstract names in this case are not helping understanding and I still think documentation example is very bad.

Comment: @Kuba: good points, absolutely helped me to understand that example better. I aggree that other names probably would have made that easier to understand, but that seems to depend on the users mindset: I would probably have got it at first read with abstract names like `memoizingKernelFunction` for `memoize` and `guiHelpWrapper` for `f`. Anyway, now John's example has convinced me that this is a very good if not the best pattern to solve such issues ...

Comment: Could you please take a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97411/12)?  If anyone, you would know if the definite answer is "no, it's not possible".

Comment: @AlbertRetey, thanks, you are right, my bad, sorry! I'll delete my comment and re-post it exactly tagging the correct user.

Comment: @RolfMertig, I am necromancing. but you aren't comparing in Apples^2. Refresh is a `HoldFirst`, and that's the overhead, it unwraps twice every iteration inside the Do. Leverage that: use  `=`, not `:=` in the definition with Refresh. `noRefr[x_] := x^3; withRefr[x_] = Refresh[x^3, None]; RepeatedTiming[Sum[withRefr[i^2], {i,10^6}]]/ RepeatedTiming[Sum[noRefr[i^2], {i,10^6}]]` returns the perfect match `{1, 1}`. in each case, one `Hold*[]` is unheld inside the Do. In this sense, `Refresh[]` adds exactly zero computiational overhead. (tested in 11.3). With the `:=` I repro your 1.28 slowdown.

Answer (score 11):

`Refresh` also has a `TrackedSymbols` option. Consider the case where several dynamic variables are declared in the first argument to `DynamicModule` but you only want updating to occur on a proper subset of those variables. An example is given at the bottom of the answer I gave to this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/990/struct-equivalent-in-mathematica/14267#14267).

Comment: This is an underrated answer.  We do this *all* the time in Mathematica code.  If you have any function which modifies any non-localized symbol for any reason, this is the only way to prevent it from non-stop tickling parent `Dynamic`s.  I have, *many* times, reported bugs to developers around the company for which the fix is to wrap their code in `Refresh[#, None]&`.  Such a change has no effect outside of `Dynamic`, but exactly the desired effect inside `Dynamic`.

Comment: @JohnFultz can't arguee with you but I'm still missing some kind of convincing example. The one provided by Rojo is not such, as I stated in comments. I mean, I havent't seen examples of Refresh that couldn't be simply replaced with Dynamic (not counting non standard usage as in my answer). Moreover, Dynamic reduces amount of reevaluated content. Could you provide such example?

Comment: @Kuba `Dynamic` evaluates to a thing with head `Dynamic`.  `Refresh` evaluates to its contents.  If you are implementing a function which can be used anywhere, but which must not trigger any enclosing `Dynamic` unnecessarily, the only way to do this is `Refresh`.  It is literally impossible to do this with `Dynamic`.  Consider, for example, a function which memoizes its results.  Inside of a `Dynamic`, such a function triggers twice because the act of memoization produces a global side effect in the symbol table which will retrigger enclosing `Dynamic`s.  `Refresh` can stop that dead.

Comment: @JohnFultz I know the Head issue, but I haven't seen any example that has Refresh as a really neat solution to it. I was always able to get what I need with nested Dynamic + TrackedSymbols and I felt like I have better control this way.  However, memoization example is a good one! I'd love to see an answer with such but not simple enough that one could workaround it with injecting / evaluating this function outside dynamics and put there under new name or something.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with Rojo's comments under his answer and I'd upvote them but the example from tutorials given in his answer is more confusing than educational for me (as expressed in comments). "For me", not "in my opinion" so maybe one can learn more from this part of tutorial.

Nevertheless, I want to show you examples were using `Refresh` really matters.

1. `Refresh` gives not head to *`expr`* which may be very useful (see comments under accepted answer)

   ```
    Dynamic[{DateString[], 2 Refresh[2, UpdateInterval -> 1]}]
   ```
2. `Refresh` matters when you have a *`Dynamic`* which isn't standard `Dynamic` that is going to be converted to `DynamicBox`, I know two exceptions:

   - First is usage `Dynamic` inside user interface elements like `Sliders`. This was pointed out by Fred Simons [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65039/5478).

     So only the first example gives expected result of updating controller:

     ```
     Slider[Dynamic[Refresh[RandomReal[], UpdateInterval -> 1]]]
     Slider[Dynamic[RandomReal[], UpdateInterval -> 1]]
     ```
   - Second is `(FrontEnd|Notebook|Cell)DynamicExpression`. If you try to do this without `Refresh`, with `Dynamics` only, you will probably fail:

     ```
     DynamicModule[{x = 0},
      Dynamic[{DateString[], x}]
      ,
      Initialization :> (  SetOptions[EvaluationCell[],
        CellDynamicExpression :> Refresh[x++, 
          UpdateInterval -> 1, TrackedSymbols :> {}]
      ]
     )]
     ```