# Dynamic and Refresh

Tags: dynamic, evaluation

If I am not mislead by my memory, in Mathematica 6 a function `Refresh` was introduced, having the options `UpdateInterval` and `TrackedSymbols`, to be used inside `Dynamic`, that did not have these options. Anyway, nowadays both `Dynamic` and `Refresh` have these options, and already many years I never use `Refresh`, with the feeling that it is a relict from long ago.

In ([What is the point of Refresh if Dynamic has an UpdateInterval option?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14368/what-is-the-point-of-refresh-if-dynamic-has-an-updateinterval-option)), more or less the same was remarked by @Tom Wellington:

> I haven' t found an example where I can' t get rid of `Refresh[]`.

In the answer to that question, an example from the documentation was given. But in that example, we can replace `Refresh` with `Dynamic` with the same effect, so for me the question remains open.

Now I happened to find the following behaviour:

```
Column[{Dynamic[RandomReal[],UpdateInterval->0.5],
  Slider[Dynamic[RandomReal[],UpdateInterval->0.5]],
  Slider[Dynamic[Refresh[RandomReal[],UpdateInterval->0.5]]]}]
```

The first `Dynamic` updates normally. With the same expression in a slider, it does not update at all, but when we wrap it in `Refresh`, it updates.

Another example:

```
Column[{Slider[Dynamic[x]],
  Slider[Dynamic[1-x, TrackedSymbols:>{}]],
  Slider[Dynamic[1-x, TrackedSymbols:>{},UpdateInterval->0.5]],
  Slider[Dynamic[Refresh[1-x, TrackedSymbols:>{},UpdateInterval->0.5]]]}]
```

When we move the first slider, the second and the third slider are immediately updated, while the second slider should not update at all and the third slider only two times per second. The last slider, with the first argument wrapped in `Refresh`, behaves as expected.

It looks a little bit that we can use the options `TrackedSymbols` and `UpdateInterval` in `Dynamic` only when this `Dynamic` is a 'stand-alone' expression. As soon as it is part of a controller, we have to use `Refresh` if we want to use these options. I have not seen this documentated. Am I right?

Comment: There is a difference in the cell expressions that might be significant.  My LinkSnooper is broken since our license renewal a couple of days ago, so I can only speculate.  (The plain `Dynamic` is a `DynamicBox`; the slider is a `SliderBox` with code, no `DynamicBox`-es.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Looks like `Slider` with `Refresh` inside behaves as standalone `Dynamic[1 - x, TrackedSymbols :> {}, UpdateInterval -> .5]`. I mean service request to update object, then call from FE on pre.link and return from kernel. It even stops when you minimize window.

Comment: So it seems this should be the answer to linked topic :)

Comment: @Michael. That is a very interesting remark, and it could well be the explanation. However, in all cases the contents of the Sliderbox is a Dynamic expression as in the kernel command, with the kernel variable x replaced with the frontend variable $CellContext`x. So it might be that the options for Dynamic do not work for frontend variables or maybe the frontend function Dynamic does not have these options. Anyway, I feel this could/should be documentated.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me now that my conjecture was too simple. Here is an example that shows that we might need `Refresh` inside a `Dynamic` that is visualized on the screen in a `DynamicBox`. The crucial point is that this `DynamicBox` is displayed in a `DynamicModuleBox`, which has an effect on the updating procedure.

Consider the following example:

```
Panel[Column[{
  Dynamic[x],
  Button["press",x=0;Pause[2];x=RandomInteger[{1,9}], Method->"Queued"]
}]]
```

When the button is pressed, during two seconds the value 0 is displayed and then the new value of `x` turns up. The option `Method->"Queued"` is essential for this behaviour.

Now I want to localize the variable `x` in a `DynamicModule`.

```
DynamicModule[{x},
  Panel[Column[{
    Dynamic[x],
    Button["press",x=0;Pause[2];x=RandomInteger[{1,9}], Method->"Queued"]
 }]]
]
```

The output shows the name of the variable that the kernel will use for the variable `x` in the displayed `DynamicModule`. Before pressing the key, evaluate the next command, with 00 replaced with the value shown.

```
Dynamic[FE`x$$00]
```

Then press the key. Before the new value is displayed, the `Dynamic` output shows the value 0, but the `DynamicModule` does not.

The reason is that when the key is pressed, the `DynamicModule` sends the button action to the kernel for evaluation, waits for the completion of this action and then adapts the display. The evaluation setting `Method->"Queued"` is used only for the auxilary kernel variable FE`x$$00.

Is it possible to force the `DynamicModule` to update the inner `Dynamic[x]` during the kernel evaluation, as with `Dynamic` not wrapped in `DynamicModule`?

The answer is yes and the solution is given by `Refresh`:

```
DynamicModule[{x},
  Panel[Column[{
    Dynamic[Refresh[x, TrackedSymbols:>{x}]],
    Button["press",x=0;Pause[2];x=RandomInteger[{1,9}], Method->"Queued"]
  }]]
]
```

See also the latest answers given to Tom Wellingtons' question mentioned above.

Comment: One doesn't need `Refresh` there is some difference between `Dynamic[x]` and `Dynamic[something more complex than symbol name]`. Undocumented and causing a lot of headaches :/. The point is: `Dynamic[List@x]` will do too.

Comment: Highly surprising. Dynamic[x] fails without Refresh, but Dynamic[x+0] and Dynamic[1*x] work without. Dynamic[Identity[x]] and Dynamic[#&[x]] fail. In these examples we have a non-atomic argument of Dynamic that evaluates to x. I cannot imagine that this is as intended. Could you post a question on this different behaviour of Dynamic?

Comment: Yep, those hidden rules are terrible, not that I can't agree, but because I don't know what to expect :) I will try to post a question later but I suppose only John can answer ;)

Comment: Sorry for a delay, done: [100828](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100828/5478)

Comment: other related questions/answers: [86401](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86401/169), and [103354](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103354/169)