# Dynamic does not update when wrapped in DynamicModule

Tags: dynamic

I'm trying to wrap some dynamic code into `DynamicModule` to localize all the variables, yet when I do that, the variables stop updating.

That does not happen if I use `Module` instead. However, the variables get highlighted in red and when I hover over them with the mouse pointer the following message pops up: "A variable was used where it is probably not going to be evaluated before going out of scope".

The code in question is from Pickett's answer to my earlier question ([AJAX-style HTTP calls triggered by a variable change](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86287/ajax-style-http-calls-triggered-by-a-variable-change)):

```
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";
callback[_, "data", data_] := choices = extractsAddresses@First@FromCharacterCode[data]

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
extractsAddresses[data_] := ToAssociations[ImportString[data, "JSON"]][["results", All, "formatted_address"]]

fetchChoices[addr_] := URLFetchAsynchronous[
  url,
  callback,
  "Parameters" -> {"address" -> addr}
  ]

Column[{
  InputField[
   Dynamic[s, (fetchChoices[#]; s = #) &],
   String,
   ContinuousAction -> True
   ],
  Dynamic@choices
  }]
```

And here is the version wrapped in `DynamicModule`:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
DynamicModule[{url, callback, choices = "", fetchChoices, s},
 url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";
 callback[_, "data", data_] := 
  choices = extractsAddresses@First@FromCharacterCode[data];
 extractsAddresses[data_] := 
  ToAssociations[ImportString[data, "JSON"]][["results", All, 
    "formatted_address"]];
 fetchChoices[addr_] := 
  URLFetchAsynchronous[url, callback, 
   "Parameters" -> {"address" -> addr}];
 Column[{InputField[Dynamic[s, (fetchChoices[#]; s = #) &], String, 
    ContinuousAction -> True], Dynamic@choices}]
 ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect that it has something to do with the asynchronous nature of the callback -- somehow `Dynamic@choices` is not tracking that kind of change.  As a quick and dirty work-around, try `Dynamic[choices, UpdateInterval->0]` instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are actually not doing anything wrong but have found one of those cases where the automatic dependency tracking doesn't work (I think this is a bug and is also discussed in other questions, e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100828/169), [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99696/169) or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103354/169)). You can make the code work (version 10.1 on Windows) by explicitly telling the last `Dynamic` to track `choices`:

```
 Dynamic[choices,TrackedSymbols:>{choices}]
```

There are some things in your code that I probably would solve different (e.g. `url` is a constant and it is also unusual to localize function names like `callback` and `fetchChoices` as `DynamicModule` variables, also your function definitions would probably be better put into the `Initialization` option of `DynamicModule`). Here is a version which should work using the usual conventions:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
With[{url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json"},
    DynamicModule[{choices="",string},
        Column[{
            InputField[
                Dynamic[string,(fetchChoices[#];string=#)&],
                String,ContinuousAction->True
            ],
            Dynamic[choices,TrackedSymbols:>{choices}]
        }],

        Initialization:>(
            Needs["GeneralUtilities`"];
            callback[_,"data",data_]:=(
                choices=extractAddresses@First@FromCharacterCode[data]
            );
            extractAddresses[data_]:=ToAssociations[
                ImportString[data,"JSON"]
            ][["results",All,"formatted_address"]];
            fetchChoices[addr_]:=URLFetchAsynchronous[
                url,callback,"Parameters"->{"address"->addr}
            ];
        )
    ]
]
```

when playing with this you will find that sometimes the shown choices seem to not match the current string. I think that is because it is not guaranteed that the asynchronous callbacks will return in the order in which they are issued. You might need to handle that for a real application, e.g. only update `choices` when the received value is from a later call then the currently shown...

Comment: Albert, thanks for your comments. Just to clarify, if I were to put function definitions into the `Initialization` option, wouldn't that create global variables? Or should I wrap the whole `DynamicModule` with `Block` or `With` and move static variables and function definitions there?

Comment: No, `Block` and `With` won't help or work for these. You can make the symbols used as function names local to `DynamicModule`, the code in the `Initialization` option is also having access to the local variables. Doing that seems to work alright, but I'm not sure if I can forsee all the consequences that would have, though. An alternative would be to put them in an own namespace (`Context`), e.g. one which is unique to the cell in which that `DynamicModule` lives...