# CheckboxBar doesn't work with TrackedSymbols

Tags: bugs, dynamic

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.0.0**

---

`CheckboxBar` doesn't work with `TrackedSymbols` and a custom callback function.

Here's an example that doesn't work

```
x = {}
CheckboxBar[Dynamic[x, Print, TrackedSymbols :> {x}], {1, 2, 3}]
```

whereas this works

```
CheckboxBar[Dynamic[x, Print], {1, 2, 3}]
```

It took me a few hours to find this, as I usually use auxiliary functions that set `TrackedSymbols` systematically, as this is really necessary when the amount of dynamic user interface elements displayed at the same time gets big.

The question is why it doesn't work with `TrackedSymbols` although it's probably a bug.

Comment: definitely looks like a bug

Comment: I agree. it not only looks a bug -- it walks and talks like a bug. Report it to WRI.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate: [65039](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65039/5478), related: [78580](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78580/5478)

Comment: `TogglerBar` has a problem too. The symptoms are not exactly the same.
`TogglerBar[Dynamic[x, Print, TrackedSymbols :> {x}], {1, 2, 3}]` gives 3 buttons but when you push them, it print nothing.

Comment: Have yo sent a bug report?

Comment: Yes I have, for both cases.