# What is the purpose of Refresh?

Tags: dynamic

I never quite understood the point of Refresh.

Why would I do this:

```
Dynamic[Refresh[DateString[], UpdateInterval -> 1]]
```

when it is the same as

```
Dynamic[DateString[], UpdateInterval -> 1]
```

Comment: It extends with tracked symbols, also useful in 'monitor' to reduce overhead.

Comment: @rasher but what about the example about, isn't it a superfluous function with options to Dynamic like TrackedSymbols and UpdateInterval?

Comment: @M.R. There's certainly crossover in functionality - I'm looking for an old answer (from *kguler* IIRC) that outlines the important differences in this same context, no luck finding it yet... Ah - got it - take a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14368/what-is-the-point-of-refresh-if-dynamic-has-an-updateinterval-option?rq=1) - might be enlightening.

Comment: I think my answer outlines nicely where you have to use `Refresh`: [What is the point of Refresh](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78580/5478). Don't you think that topic duplicates yours?