# How can I decouple the updating of a `LocatorPane`'s background from changes in its point variables?

Tags: dynamic, graphics

I am building a `Dynamic` application and I'm having some trouble understanding exactly how [`Refresh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refresh.html) should be implemented.

The main point of work for this is a [`LocatorPane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocatorPane.html), whose background has two parts: (a) one which depends on the value of its `Locator`, and (b) one which depends on external variables, combined using `Show`. The dependence on the `Locator` is easy and quick to implement, but the dependence on the external variables is slower. I would like to separate these two tracks so that part (b) is only evaluated when it is needed. That is, I want updates of the `Locator` position to only trigger updating of part (a).

A simple working example is the following:

```
DynamicModule[
 {a = 0.5, point = {1, 1}},
 Column[{
   Slider[Dynamic[a]],
   LocatorPane[
    Dynamic[point],
    Dynamic[
     Show[
      ContourPlot[
       Sin[a x y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}
       , ImageSize -> 300, PlotRangePadding -> None
       ],
      Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, point}]]
      ]
     ]
    ],
   Dynamic[point]
   }]
 ]
```

Here changing the value of `a` via the slider causes the `ContourPlot` to update, which makes it go fuzzy (at a lower number of `PlotPoints`) while it is recalculated. This is expected behaviour. However, clicking on the `LocatorPane` also causes this behaviour, which is unnecessary as it's only the `Line` that needs to be updated.

Thus:

[image]

Now this is the expected behaviour from the code as written, and Mathematica needs to be told explicitly to hold off evaluation, on which bits of the plot, and in which conditions.

From what I understand of the [`Refresh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refresh.html) documentation, it should suffice to contain the `ContourPlot` inside a `Refresh` call, setting the [`TrackedSymbols`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackedSymbols.html) to `a`. However, the resulting code,

```
DynamicModule[
 {a = 0.5, point = {1, 1}},
 Column[{
   Slider[Dynamic[a]],
   LocatorPane[
    Dynamic[point],
    Dynamic[
     Show[
      Refresh[
       ContourPlot[
        Sin[a x y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}
        , ImageSize -> 300, PlotRangePadding -> None
        ]
       , TrackedSymbols -> {a}
       ],
      Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, point}]]
      ]
     ]
    ],
   Dynamic[point]
   }]
 ]
```

has the same behaviour as above. Moreover, trying to encase the `Refresh` in a nested `Dynamic` call simply causes `Show` to give an error message (Could not combine the graphics objects). On the other extreme, putting the whole `Show` inside the `Refresh` scope causes the `Line` to freeze and stop following the pointer around until the slider is manipulated.

How can I successfully decouple the dynamic updating of these two parts of the background, so that each part will only update when it needs to?

Comment: `Refresh` tells what to do to the `Dynamic` it is in, and the whole `Dynamic` will be updated, it can not focus only on `Refresh`. This is tricky function :) a little related: [78580](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78580/5478)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about how to use `Refresh` in this case, but without it enclosing `Show` *and* `point` in `Dynamic` works:

```
DynamicModule[{a = 0.5, point = {1, 1}},
 Column@{
   Slider@Dynamic@a,
   LocatorPane[
    Dynamic@point,
    Dynamic@Show[
      ContourPlot[Sin[a x y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
       ImageSize -> 300, PlotRangePadding -> None],
      Graphics@Line@{{0, 0}, Dynamic@point}
      ]
    ], Dynamic@point
   }
 ]
```

This way only the inner `Dynamic@point` is triggered when changing the value of `point`.