# Why NotebookDynamicExpression freezes Mathematica on this particular application?

Tags: front-end, dynamic

Why does this simple expression freezes Mathematica?
(version 10.3.0, Windows 7 64)

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 NotebookDynamicExpression :> (Dynamic[
    Refresh[If[! NumericQ[myColorID], myColorID = 1]; 
     myColorID = If[myColorID == 2, 1, 2], UpdateInterval -> 0.5], 
    TrackedSymbols -> {}])]
```

And yet, when I do just the Dynamic part, it works fine:

```
Dynamic[Refresh[If[! NumericQ[myColorID], myColorID = 1]; 
  myColorID = If[myColorID == 2, 1, 2], UpdateInterval -> 0.5], 
 TrackedSymbols -> {}]
```

(and the same problem exists when using `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, FrontEndDynamicExpression :>...`  )

Comment: Freezes 10.2 on linux too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why it doesn't work, but you can skip `Dynamic` and put `TrackedSymbols` to `Refresh`. With this setup it won't make any troubles.

```
SetOptions[
 EvaluationNotebook[], 
 NotebookDynamicExpression :> Refresh[
  If[! NumericQ[myColorID], myColorID = 1]; 
  myColorID = If[myColorID == 2, 1, 2], 
  UpdateInterval -> 0.5, 
  TrackedSymbols -> {}
 ]
]
```

`Notebook|FE|Cell DynamicExpressions` are by default wrapped/treated as `Dynamic` by `FrontEnd`, this is why we could do this.

Here's an answer where I;ve shown that `Dynamic/Refresh` behaviour in those options is slightly different: [What is the point of Refresh?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78580/5478)

Comment: thank you. I'm reporting it as a bug.

Comment: @P.Fonseca ok, good luck :)