# Speed of flow of time in Dynamic ClockGauges

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, date-and-time

Currently trying to utilise the `ClockGauge` function to display two clocks side-by-side that have different `UpdateInterval`. The end goal is to create some sort of relativistic time dilation tool like [this one](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RelativisticTimeDilation/) except include preset options to choose different satellites like GPS, GLONASS etc. and hence, calculate both special and general effects of relativity. However, I can't get the clocks to display different update intervals? Any suggestions?

Code below:

```
Dynamic[
  Row[
    {Refresh[
       ClockGauge[AbsoluteTime[], PlotLabel -> Style["Local", Bold, Large]], 
       (UpdateInterval -> 1)], 
     Refresh[
       ClockGauge[AbsoluteTime[], PlotLabel -> Style["LocalDelayed", Bold, Large]], 
       (UpdateInterval -> 10)]}]]
```

Comment: Replace refresh with dynamic

Comment: And drop the `Dynamic` at the front. i.e. take your code and do this: `code // First[#]/.Refresh->Dynamic&`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need something else but first let's discuss the problem you have with your code.

#### OP's approach

By using:

```
Dynamic[ 
  ... 
  Refresh[... UpdateInterval -> x]
  Refresh[... UpdateInterval -> y]
  ...
]
```

you make the parent `Dynamic` updated each `Min[x,y]`. `Refresh` are not handled separately, it is `Dynamic` that governs updating at the end. See [What is the point of Refresh if Dynamic has an UpdateInterval option?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14368/5478) and read related sections in tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.

So you need to do:

```
  (*parent dynamic dropped, nothing outside gauges needs updating*)
Row[{ 
  ... 
  Dynamic[ClockGauge... UpdateInterval -> 1]
  Dynamic[ClockGauge... UpdateInterval -> 10]
  ...
}]
```

The best would be to keep only the time dynamic, not the whole gauge but `ClockGauge` does not support `Dynamic` arguments e.g. `Gauge[Dynamic[time]...]`

#### My approach

Finally, I don't think this is what you want. It will result with two clocks showing current time but one will tick each second while the other each 10 seconds.

You would probably prefer to show clocks where time passes with different speeds:

```
With[{start = AbsoluteTime[]}, 
 Dynamic[
  Row[{
   ClockGauge[start + Clock[{0, 10^6, .1}, 1/2 10^6], 
     PlotLabel -> Style["Local\n x 2", Bold, Large]],
   ClockGauge[start + Clock[{0, 10^6, .1}, 1/0.5 10^6], 
     PlotLabel -> Style["Local Delayed\n x 0.5", Bold, Large]]
  }],
  UpdateInterval -> .1]
]
```

[image]

Notice that I use one `Dynamic` now because we control 'speed' with `Clock`.

Sorry if I missed your point.