# Problem when using TrackedSymbols and UpdateInterval to refresh different expressions at different times inside Dynamic

Tags: functions, dynamic, scheduling

While attempting to optimize my program, I noticed an issue with the Refresh expressions I am using inside a particular `Dynamic[]`. I will use a simplified example to illustrate the problem.

Suppose I have the following variables and `InputFields`:

```
clockVar = Dynamic[Round[Clock[5]]];
x = 1;
y = 1;

InputField[Dynamic[x]]
InputField[Dynamic[y]]
```

Now, suppose I create the following `Dynamic` plot:

```
Dynamic[
  Refresh[
    a = 2 * x;
    Print["a refreshed"];
  ,TrackedSymbols :> {x}
  ];

  Refresh[
    b = 2 * y;
    Print["b refreshed"];
 ,TrackedSymbols :> {y}
 ];

 Refresh[
   c = Setting[clockVar];
   Print["c refreshed"];
 ,UpdateInterval -> 1
 ];

 ListPlot[{{a, 0}, {0, b}, {c, c}}]
]
```

The first refresh block is meant to refresh its contents only when the value of `x` is changed, the second refresh block is meant to refresh its contents only when the value of `y` is changed, and the third refresh block is meant to refresh its contents every second.

However, when observing the output of the `Print[]` statements, it is clear that , instead, all three refresh blocks refresh every second (presumably because of the option `UpdateInterval -> 1` in the third refresh block).

Further, if I get rid of the third Refresh block, that is:

```
Dynamic[
  Refresh[
    a = 2 * x;
    Print["a refreshed"];
  ,TrackedSymbols :> {x}
  ];

  Refresh[
    b = 2 * y;
    Print["b refreshed"];
 ,TrackedSymbols :> {y}
 ];

 ListPlot[{{a, 0}, {0, b}}]
]
```

then, if I change either `x` or `y`, both Refresh blocks refresh their contents.

I have spent a few hours now experimenting with different nesting of the `Refresh` statements, and have looked through the `Refresh[]` and `Dynamic[]` documentation, but I cannot seem to find a solution to this problem.

If someone with more knowledge about how `Dynamic[]` and `Refresh[]` work can explain the problem, and suggest ways to approach circumventing this problem, I would be greatly appreciative. In particular, I need a general solution, since the problematic `Dynamic[]` in my program involves complicated user-defined functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What eventually is 'refreshed' is the parent `Dynamic`, not only what is inside `Refresh`. `Refresh` tells outer `Dynamic` what to care about. And if there are many `Refresh` specifications then the outer `Dynamic` will care about all of that.

And at the end of the day the whole content of `Dynamic` is evaluated again. So each of `Refresh/Print` expressions as well. That is why you see print associated with `y` when only `x` changed. The same applies to updates caused by `UpdateInterval`.

If you want to 'track' separate changes you really need to have separate `Dynamic`/`DynamicWrappers` for them:

```
Row[{
  Dynamic @ ListPlot[{{a, 0}, {0, b}}],

  Dynamic[ a = 2 * x; Print["a refreshed"];"",             TrackedSymbols :> {x}],
  Dynamic[ b = 2 * y; Print["b refreshed"];"",             TrackedSymbols :> {y}],
  Dynamic[ c = Setting[clockVar]; Print["c refreshed"];"", UpdateInterval -> 1]
}]
```

Even better would be to trigger changes from the controller that changes `x/y` e.g.:

```
Slider @ Dynamic[x, (x = #; a = 2 x)& ]
```

Related topic:

[What is the point of Refresh if Dynamic has an UpdateInterval option?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14368/5478)