# Dynamic influenced by a countdown Clock ignores actions in second argument

Tags: function-construction, dynamic, special-functions, scoping, date-and-time

I stripped a `Dynamic` down to its bare essentials. `Dynamic` doesn't execute any of the functions asked for in second argument. Once the `countdown` completes a cycle (recurring Clock) it should at a minimum do `(Ding[]; NotebookSave[];)` however ideally I would prefer it did all of this `(Ding[]; NotebookSave[]; x = "saved"; Pause[3])`.  Please help me solve this.

```
countdown[s_ : 10, n_ : 3] = Dynamic[s - Clock[{0, s, 1}, s, n]];

Ding[v_ : 3/5] := 
  Quiet@EmitSound[
    Sound[{SoundNote["G#6", .3, "Marimba", SoundVolume -> v]}]];

DynamicModule[
 {s = 6, n = 3, t, x},
 t = countdown[s, n];
 Dynamic[x,
  If[t == 0, (Ding[]; NotebookSave[]; x = "saved"; Pause[3]),
    #] &, Initialization :> (x = t), TrackedSymbols :> {x, t}]
 ]
```

Comment: (1) The second argument of `Dynamic` is called only "during interactive changing or editing." There is no interactive changing or editing here. (2) `t` displays as an integer, but its head is `Dynamic`. So `t == 0` is never `True` and never `False`. Use `Setting[t] == 0` instead.  But it never gets executed here because of point (1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following? I didn't understand all the extra variables, so I stripped down the code more. In a complicated case, you might need `Dynamic@Refresh` instead of just `Dynamic`; see [What is the point of Refresh if Dynamic has an UpdateInterval option?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14368/what-is-the-point-of-refresh-if-dynamic-has-an-updateinterval-option) and related Q&A on `Refresh`.  You'd probably have to put the output in a docked cell, since the FE updates `Dynamic` objects only if they're "on-screen."

```
DynamicModule[{t, saved = False},
 t = Dynamic@Clock[{0, 6, 1}];
 Dynamic[
  If[! saved && Setting@t <= 1,
   Ding[];
   (*NotebookSave[];*)
   saved = True,
   saved = False]
  ; t
  , TrackedSymbols :> {t}
  , UpdateInterval -> 1]
 ]
```

Comment: thank you this worked. funny that you mention `DockedCell` as this `Dynamic` is embedded in an `AttachCell` but callled fron a `Button` in a `DockedCell`. reason for no Refresh is that t depends on countdown which depends on Clock. Dynamic automatically refreshes any expression tied to a Clock using Clock's own UpdateInterval.

Comment: @JulesManson You're welcome. The reason `Refresh` might be or might not be needed is different. (For instance, `UpdateInterval -> 1` is needed, or seems to be: `Dynamic` does not automatically refresh without it in my test.) `Refresh[expr,...]` allows you to control whether `expr` is updated without updating the whole code. In complicated user interfaces, this can save time and make the UI more responsive. Whether it's needed or helpful depends on the overall design, and I didn't know how simplified your mini-example is.

Comment: I have not used `AttachCell`.  If it moves far enough off screen, the dynamic updating might not occur.

Comment: Fantastic argument for including a redundant `Refresh`  when `Dynamic[expr...` depends on a `Clock`. I have found `AttachCell` to be a wonderful alternative to `DockedCell` when placing `AttachCell` with respect to `EvaluationNotebook` rather than another `Cell` so that it never scrolls out of view.

Comment: @JulesManson Sounds nice. I just tried it and it made Mathematica crash. :(