# How to define UpValues in a different context from within a package

Tags: packages, scoping, contexts, upvalues

I'm trying to create a function (in a package) to import a lot of data and create a symbol with UpValues to return specific results about the data. I've got it working fine in a regular notebook, but when I define the function within a package I can't get it to work properly.

A simple example of my problem:

TestPackage.m:

```
BeginPackage["TestPackage`"];

testFunction::usage= "testFunction[] does all kind of interesting things.";

Begin["`Private`"]

testFunction[name_Symbol]:=
 Module[{},(
  ClearAll[name];
  UpValues[name]=
   {
    test[name]->"hello!"
   };
  Protect[name];
 )]

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

I then call the function in a regular notebook:

```
Needs["TestPackage`", "/path/to/TestPackage.m"]

testFunction[a]
```

- `test[a]` returns `test[a]`
- and `` TestPackage`Private`test[a] `` returns the expected `"hello!"`

How do I change `testFunction` so that `test[a]` also returns `"hello!"`?

Comment: Welcome to [Mathematica.se]! I cannot tell you how much I appreciate your efforts in correctly marking up your question. Although, I did fix the issue with context names, which involved wrapping the whole thing in double grave marks, not single ones, but most people are not aware of that. I would encourage you to register your account so you can more fully participate here. Again, welcome, and I hope to see you here again.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome @rcollyer! And for fixing my source, I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Comment: You're welcome. Three questions. 1. Why are you setting `UpValues[...]` directly, instead of using either `UpSet` (`^=`) or `TagSet` (`name /: test[name] = ...`) directly? 2. Have you tried setting a `usage` string on `test`, or if you have considered that why doesn't it do what you need? 3. Do you have any purpose for `Module` other than to provide convenient structure, as it doesn't do anything in your code?

Comment: 2 answers and 1 question in return: 1. I didn't know about `UpSet`. It seems to produce the same results though. What's the difference between setting the values directly and using `UpSet`? 2. Where would I set a usage string on `test`? In the function definition or somewhere else? 3. It's true that `Module` doesn't serve any purpose here. It does however in the actual function I'm trying to write, which also needs a couple of temporary variables to store results. I thought it wise to include `Module`, since it also deals with scopes.

Comment: 1. There's no difference between what you're doing and `UpSet`, just that `UpSet` is the common way of accomplishing what you're doing, so more readily recognizable. 2. Set the usage string in the preamble of the package like you do for `testFunction`. 3. I figured that was the reason, but I encountered at least one person who believed it was performing localization while using it like in your code.

Comment: Excellent question style: clearly formatted, minimal working example, ... I'm impressed (+1)! Welcome here. Anyway, I think it would be good if you add another **Details** section to your question where you explain a bit further what your goal is. I have the feeling that just answering your question is not the best possible help you can get. Maybe we can help you with the overall approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The explanation can be found in the doc to `BeginPackage` and `Begin`

> - `` BeginPackage["context`"] `` makes `` context` `` and `` System` ``the only active contexts.
> - `` Begin["context`"] `` resets the current context.

Therefore, at the moment you first mention the symbol `test` it is **not** created it in the `Global` context. This can be seen from you (simplified) example

```
BeginPackage["TestPackage`"];
testFunction::usage = 
  "testFunction[] does all kind of interesting things.";
Begin["`Private`"];
testFunction[name_Symbol] := name /: test[name] := "hello!";
End[];
EndPackage[]

testFunction[a]
UpValues[a]

(* {HoldPattern[TestPackage`Private`test[a]] :> "hello!"} *)
```

beside giving `test` a `::usage` message, you can give the context explicitly

```
testFunction[name_Symbol] := name /: Global`test[name] := "hello!";
```

### Further note

- I don't see why you use `Module` because you don't *localize* any variable. And if you want to input a sequence of commands, divided by `;` (called a `CompoundExpression`) you can simply wrap it in parenthesis, as you did.
- Your combination of `ClearAll` and `Protect` is such that you can call `testFunction` on a given Symbol only one time.  On the second call you get messages since `ClearAll` cannot clear a protected symbol. What is the intention behind this?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 1. Adding a `::usage` message fixes the problem. I won't set the context explicitly, because I also want to call the function from other contexts than ``Global` ``. 2. Module is not used here, but will be used in the full package. 3. I used `Protect` because it prevents from accidentally setting a value to `name` which prevents the `UpValues` form working correctly. If there is a better way, I'd like to hear it. Thanks again!

Comment: @jlmr you may wish to `Unprotect` the Symbol at the beginning of your module.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 7):

You should export the test symbol, ie define it between `` BeginPackage["TestPackage`"] `` and `` Begin["`Private`"] ``, for example by giving a usage to test.

```
test::usage = "test[name] returns ..."
(*or just*) test;
```

for your definition, as said already in comments, I would use

```
test[name] ^= "hello";
```

My answer to this post contains many application of UpValues, it could interest you: [Struct equivalent in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/990/66)

You could also not export the symbol, that will be thus in the Private context of the package, and use the full name of test

```
TestPackage`Private`test[name] ^= "hello";
```