# Missing definition of some parts of function?

Tags: packages

I have:

```
BeginPackage["Test1`"];
ClearAll[f];
f::usage = "";
Begin["`Private`"];
f[x_AA]:= 1;
f[x_BB]:= 2; 
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

When later, on a notebook, after the call package successful with:

```
<<Test1`
```

I always get from evaluated:

```
x = AA[3];
f[x]
```

It should be: `1`. But, actually, It is `f[AA[3]]`. 
The issue is same if I used `x = BB[4]`;

Any idea? I don't realize how to make it works.

Comment: That `Print[1]` prints 1 is actually not its *result*, it's a *side-effect*. Just try `Print[1] // FullForm` and you get Null.

Comment: This question can be found  here, the answer useful: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7502/7251

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(15870)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15870/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AA and BB in the definition of f are local symbols of the Test1`context. If you want to use them in the Global context you have to export them from the package or you have to precede them with their context:

```
f[Test1`Private`AA[3]]
```

> 1

Or

```
BeginPackage["Test1`"];
ClearAll[f];
f::usage = "";
AA::usage = "";
BB::usage = "";
Begin["`Private`"];
f[x_AA] := 1;
f[x_BB] := 2;
End[];
EndPackage[];

f[AA[3]]
```

> 1

Comment: Oh, sure. it is a solution. Thanks.

Comment: It actually suffices to include the line `AA; BB;` just before the `Begin[]` if you don't want to bother with writing usage messages for them.

Comment: I'm just repeating the OP's original pattern, assuming he left the usage string empty to reduce the size of the example.