# Assign a value to a variable without using Set or SetDelayed?

Tags: evaluation

I supose probably yes, but at the end I assume that internally mathematica has to use Set or SetDelayed. Am I right?

Background: I am developing a super simple phraser that takes a code description how objects should work and changes it slightly. Part of the code deals with assignments. They have to be handled in a somewhat special way.

The generic indexing works like

```
OBJ[id_]@f := f[id]
```

I noticed that during the assignments *Mathematica* does not bring `OBJ[1]@f to the bitter end, i.e.,`f[1]`; for example in

```
OBJ[1]@f = 1
```

the left hand side is not resolved to `f[1]`.

I changed how `Set` and `SetDelayed` works for fields in objects, and would like to make sure that *Mathematica* always goes through my definitions:

```
OBJ /: Set[OBJ[id_]@f, rhs_] := (f[id] = rhs);
OBJ /: SetDelayed[OBJ[id_]@f, rhs_] := (f[id] := rhs);
OBJ /: OBJ[id_][f] := (f[id]);
```

the first two lines handle the cases like

```
OBJ[1]@f = 1;
OBJ[2]@f := 2;
```

while the third line handles the cases like

```
a = 2 * OBJ[1]@f + 1
```

of course, a combination is possible:

```
OBJ[1]@f = OBJ[2]@f + 1;
```

I am providing the background to the question, which should hopefully put the question in the right context. Hope someone can help.

Comment: If you're asking whether there are other ways to change values than `Set`, yes, there are: `AppendTo`, `Increment`, `AddTo`, and probably many others I can't recall ...

Comment: of course, a field could be a list. thanks! so the construct above simply sucks. there are 10000 ways to bypass it.

Comment: You have a typo in your definitions. You defined `OJB` while you're using `OBJ` elsewhere... `Set` has attribute `HoldFirst`, so that you can make assignments like `a = 1` even when `a` has a value. Try using `Evaluate` on the LHS.

Comment: thanks for spoting the typo. alas, the behavior has nothing to do with it. it is the way set and setdelayed behave.

Comment: @zorank I also explained why they behave that way in my previous comment... they have the `HoldFirst` attribute. An `Evaluate` should fix that. In the off-chance that you're using this to emulate some OO like concepts, I would recommend taking a look here: [Once more on object orientation in Mathematica: does it have to be so hard?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16869)

Comment: I did not ignore your comment. the problem is that it cannot fix in the context I am developing the code. I am working on a phraser that should be very generic. I'll check the link. thanks!