# Error changing Dataset using Part

Tags: bugs, version-10, data-structures, dataset

**Update**

It was a bug in the documentation of V10.0, this functionality was not implemented yet, and V10.1 changed the documentation, removing it. It's a pity, because it's a very useful operations, common in other languages like `R`. I miss `data.frame` like notation in Mathematica.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

In the new guide [Computation With Structured Datasets](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ComputationWithStructuredDatasets.html)
we can find this part, on how to change a [Dataset](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html)

[image]

But if we create a `Dataset` like:

```
ds=Dataset[{<|"a"->1,"b"->"x"|>,<|"a"->2,"b"->"y"|>,<|"a"->6,"b"->"z"|>}];
```

And then make:

```
ds[[1, 1]] = 2
```

Or, closer to my real case test:

```
ds[[All, "a"]] = Accumulate@Normal@ds[[All, "a"]]
```

We get an error:

> "Part specification ds[[1,1]] is longer than depth of object"
>
> "Part specification ds[[All,1]] is longer than depth of object. "

Is this a Bug?

Setting is not working on `Dataset` as stated by documentation.

[This post on Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/289999?p_p_auth=ki31GcHN)

Comment: Unfortunately not in V10.0.1 yet...

Comment: `StringReplace[%,"V10.0.1"-> "V10.0.2"]`

Comment: `StringReplace[%%,"V10.0.1"-> "V10.1.0"]`

Comment: This is no longer documented to work as of 10.1.0. As Tali mentions in his answer below, the inclusion of this comment in the original documentation was erroneous.

Comment: @StefanR I know about that. But this would be a nice way to handler data, and should be considered in the future. In `R`, it's a very natural way to do Data Frame manipulations.

Comment: @Murta I edited bug information to conform with the standard header here: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/standard-header-for-bugs-tagged-posts-for-easy-searching.  I removed [tag:version-10] because that also is the policy adopted by the community here: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1361/how-should-we-tag-longstanding-bugs-that-have-been-fixed.  I certainly didn't mean to change the intention of your post.  Perhaps, though, you could find a way to include the header and adjust the tags?

Comment: I have checked on-line documentation and experimented with Dataset L-value assignment at Wolfram cloud. It seems nothing have changed since this post. Taliesin made an interesting comment about different representations of Dataset in logical and physical data model. I wonder if there has been any progress on this ? Have you seen my [LinkedIn post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/air-atomic-information-resource-athanassios-i-hatzis-phd) on data modeling of AtomicDB using atomic information resource units that are self-referenced and uniquely identified in a 4D space ?

Answer (score 35):

I'm the developer of `Dataset`.

Yes, this is a gross documentation oversight. We planned this functionality but had to push it back to a point release. Somehow no-one caught this piece of legacy documentation.

I've filed a bug on the documentation problem right now, it's easy to fix.

As for when L-value assignment will be available, I'm hoping 10.0.1 or 10.0.2, which are in the next month or two. It gets complicated, because you might well want to write things like:

```
dataset[ Select[#age > 30&] , "salary"] *= 2
```

That's certainly a powerful kind of operation, but also hard to implement. Even part-like assignments can get complicated when you are assigning multidimensional datasets to each other.

Thanks for trying the functionality, though!

Comment: Tks for your clarification. I'll wait for it, it's a very useful operation and I'm happy that I won't need to wait for V11. Using this opportunity, have you saw [this post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/290574?p_p_auth=adlxn4BS) in Wolfram Community about Dataset memory consumption? There are plans to efficient Tabular Data in V10?

Comment: @Murta Yes, moving to column-oriented will make things much better. But before I could do that I had to lay the groundwork in the form of a type system that could represent the "logical shape", even if the "physical layout" is different. And of course Leonid is working on making this whole process scale to out-of-core computation against data that lives on disk.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon your example is quite funny !

Comment: @Taliesin, it seems there is an alternative approach to column-oriented data modeling, but I have seen very few attempts to build a fully operational database system based on this. I am talking about associative data modeling, the way it has been implemented on Qlikview (In-Memory, file based database) and on AtomicDB (full DBMS). I cannot also find any open-source implementation on this, so I decided to build one on top of graph, object-relational databases that support references to persistent objects !

Comment: I'm wondering what's the status of the problem. Looks like it's not in V11.1.

Comment: @xslittlegrass which problem? mutable updating of Datasets? i've implemented the kernel functionality that is required for it, but I don't have immediate plans to do it for Dataset. However, see the answer I just posted.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon Thanks for the updates, and thanks for listening to us! By the way, do you have any comments on this question on Dataset performance: [Dataset is 20X slow when adding column heads](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/141223/1364)

Comment: @xslittlegrass Mr. Wizard's answer is correct. With a lot of optimization work we could make Dataset opportunistically store tables in column-oriented form. Indeed that's always been the plan. But that will take months to implement properly and currently my priorities lie with neural networks.

Answer (score 21):

I have implemented the underlying kernel functionality that is needed to make this possible. However it is not yet implemented on the Dataset side. I don't think this will happen in the immediate future owing to other priorities.

Here is a stop-gap that implements a simple version of mutable updating, this of course is not production-grade. I'm happy for anyone who wants to modify this answer to extend its functionality, add error handling, etc.

```
Unprotect[Dataset];
Language`SetMutationHandler[Dataset, DatasetMutationHandler];

SetAttributes[DatasetMutationHandler, HoldAllComplete];
DatasetMutationHandler[Set[sym_Symbol[[args___]], newvalue_]] := Block[{tmp},
    tmp = Normal[sym];
    tmp[[args]] = If[Dataset`ValidDatasetQ[newvalue], Normal[newvalue], newvalue];
    sym = Dataset[tmp];
];
```

You can use it as follows:

```
In[51]:= d = Dataset[{1, 2, 3}];
d[[2 ;; 3]] = 99;
Normal[d]

Out[53]= {1, 99, 99}
```

Comment: I see that this function was added in 10.4. Is it already reliable and usable there? (I do not have a use for it at this moment, just asking for the future.)

Comment: @Szabolcs yes, it is. it's used in production to implement CloudExpression. you may notice however that Language`HasMutationHandlerQ returns the opposite of the correct answer, but it's not a very important function.

Answer (score 19):

In lieu of `Set`, the `Query` syntax offers various ways to update selective elements of a dataset.  For example, we can change the value of the field `a` in the first row like this:

```
ds[{1 -> (<| #, "a" -> 999|> &)}]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

or like this:

```
ds[{1 -> Query[{"a" -> (999 &)}]}]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Multiple fields can be updated simultaneously:

```
ds[{1 -> (<| #, "a" -> 999, "b" -> "ZZZ" |> &)}]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

We can update selective rows, in this case field "b" in rows with even `a`:

```
ds[All, If[EvenQ[#a], <| #, "b" -> "!!!!"|>, #] &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

The accumulation use case can be accomplished like this:

```
With[{a = ds[Accumulate, "a"]}
, ds @ MapIndexed[<| #, "a" -> a[[First@#2]] |> &]
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

or like this:

```
Module[{acc = 0}, ds[All, {"a" -> (acc += # &)}]]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Note that none of these operations involve destructively altering the dataset, so they should all read `ds = ds[...]` if desired.  Presumably `Set` will eventually perform destructive updates in those restricted circumstances that *Mathematica* tolerates mutation.

Comment: Examples such as these are sure to increase the fun factor for the WRI employees working to compile the `Query` language into SQL ;)

Comment: Nice examples. +1.

Comment: @WReach, are WRI employees working to compile the `Query` language into SQL? Will this be brought into `DatabaseLink`?

Comment: @ArgentoSapiens I have no current information about this.  My glib comment was based upon the fact that pre-release versions of the V10 documentation contained extensive references to such capability.  Those references were withdrawn very late, just before the official V10 release.  I speculate that the functionality under discussion in the question would (or did) prove to be challenging to support across multiple back-end technologies.

Answer (score 16):

Though I don't know what is the efficiency impact of it, a workaround could be converting the `Dataset` to `Association` by `Normal`, making the update on the `Association`, then converting it back to `Dataset`.

```
ds = Dataset[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x"|>, <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y"|>, <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z"|>}]

ds = Module[{temp = Normal[ds]},
            temp[[All, "a"]] = Accumulate[temp[[All, "a"]]];
            temp // Dataset]
```

[image: Dataset updating]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that in Mathematica 13, there is still no easy way to modify values in a `Dataset`.

Comment: Could you please add a short illustrative example using v13? Thanks.