# A documented syntax of FileNames doesn't work?

Tags: bugs, syntax, files-and-directories, documentation

**Documentation discrepancy present in 10.3 and fixed in 10.4.1**

---

According to the documentation for [`FileNames`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FileNames.html) under **Details**:

[image: FileNames[forms,dirs,{n}] includes names of directories only if they appear exactly at level n.]

However when I attempt to use this syntax I get an error:

```
FileNames["foo*", "c:\\", {2}]
```

> FileNames::innf: Non-negative integer or Infinity expected at position 3 in FileNames[foo*,c:\,{2}]. >>

I am using *Mathematica* 10.0.1 under Windows.  Does this syntax work on other systems?

Comment: I have exactly the same error message with both MMA 10.0.1.0 and MMA 9.0.1.0, on OS X 10.9.4 (when I input for example `FileNames["foo*", "/", {2}]`) Also in MMA 9.0.1.0 Documentation, the curly brackets are missing : ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TwT6W.png)

Comment: Maybe they have a *documentation driven development* at WRI. They first write the doc and then implement the stuff and some guy went home early :-)

Comment: I might argue that this is a *typographical* error in the documentation.  Removing the curly braces seems to work on v10 win7 and linux (for the few examples I've tried).

Comment: @bobthechemist That (without the `{}`) is also a documented syntax meaning down to level *n*, and yes it does seem to work.  The syntax in the question is supposed to mean "exactly at level *n*" as it says.

Comment: @halirutan I don't know if you meant that as a joke or not, but I believe that does in fact happen, and perhaps is the case here.  See: [(54491)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54491/121).  I am adding the bugs tag meaning **documentation bug.**

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I missed that subtlety, although with 20-20 hindsight it is consistent with other functions with *levelspec*.  I note that curly braces didn't work on linux v10.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It was meant only half as joke. I was referring to [test-driven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) which is similar only that you write unit tests for components that don't exist yet. Then you hit random keys until you come up with code that fulfills the test..

Comment: `?? FileNames` also knows nothing about `{n}`.

Comment: @Kuba I don't believe that I have.  Do it if you have time.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard So I got a reply that is was already reported.

Comment: Persistent in 10.2.

Comment: The behavior might persist, but as of my 10.1 (linux)  the *documentation* does not show the `{n}` form..

Comment: @george2079 Oops!  No, it's still there in the documentation section under **Details**.  **Re**-editing the header. :^)

Comment: so it is. Maybe you should put that ("under details" ) in the question.

Comment: @george2079 I should have done that from the start; its absence confused both of us and who knows how many others.  Corrected now.

Comment: The bracketed form seems to work in 10.4, at least for me on Linux.

Comment: Seems to be correctly documented in Mathematica 10.4 windows edition. (also the markup with the {n} brackets seems to work, even though it is not documented anymore)

Comment: @Frank I did not see your comment until now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was fixed in 10.4.1

Posting this wiki answer to reduce the unanswered questions stack

```
FileNames["D*", $InstallationDirectory, {2}]
```

> ```
> {"C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\10.4\\SystemFiles\\Data", 
>  "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\10.4\\SystemFiles\\Devices", 
>  "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\10.4\\SystemFiles\\Dictionaries"}
> ```

Comment: `FileNames["foo*", "c:\\", {2}]` cannot run normally still.

Comment: @yode yes, but it seems it is a different bug now :)