# Wolfram Data Framework specification?

Tags: export, import, data, conversion, wolfram-data-framework

Motivated by a recent question on the meaning of all sorts of W* acronyms, 
I would like to get more information about the *Wolfram Data Framework* (WDF).
On its web page http://www.wolfram.com/data-framework/ it says:

> "WDF is a human-readable plaintext format that can be rendered in JSON, XML and other forms."

While the specifications of *XML* and *JSON* are well known and documented,
I do not know about the specifications of *WDF*. How does it differ from *XML* or *JSON*, what are its advantages above other data specification formats?

If I read e.g. an XML file into *Mathematica* I get a `SymbolicXML` expression.
Does this have anything to do with WDF?

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Moreover, this in another case of [**documentation driven development**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60540/a-documented-syntax-of-filenames-doesnt-work#comment172397_60540) because `guide/WDFWolframDataFramework` proudly shows `Export` section. Now I challenge you to export/export string anything to `.wdf`.

Comment: I'd report it to support@wolfram.com

Comment: @Kuba This simply has to be a joke, right? It explicitly says "Export - export WDF to a file (.wdf, ... )" for 2+ years now in the guide ["WDF (Wolfram Data Framework)"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WDFWolframDataFramework.html)? -- And I just took up your challenge with an `Association` and `$Failed`...