# What can the *MutationHandler* functions do?

Tags: core-language, undocumented, object-oriented

So in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/141916/38205) we see the only use I know of of the function `` Language`SetMutationHandler ``.

And just to see what it could do I tried it on one version of my OOP frameworks (this one cooked directly into a chemistry package):

```
SetAttributes[ChemObjectMutationHandler, HoldAllComplete];
ChemObjectMutationHandler[
   Set[sym_Symbol?ChemObjectQ[prop_], newvalue_]
   ] :=
  ChemSet[sym, prop, newvalue];
obj_ChemObject?ChemObjectQ[prop_] :=
  ChemGet[obj, prop];
Language`SetMutationHandler[ChemObject, ChemObjectMutationHandler];
```

Then I tested it by just trying to assign a property to an object:

```
co = ChemImport["methyloxirane"];

co["Property"]

Missing["KeyAbsent", "Property"]

co["Property"] = 1

ChemGet[co, "Property"]

1
```

And it seems to have worked. The fact that the [`ChemGet`](http://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1.paclets/reference/ChemTools/ref/ChemGet.html) call (basically just a pull from a hash table) worked and that the [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) remain empty is comforting:

```
co // DownValues

{}
```

So my question is this, what else can this function handle? I took that usage pattern directly from the linked answer, but not knowing how the function sets its hooks / what hooks it's setting it's hard to know what else I can do. What forms of mutability can it introduce?

Also there are three other functions like that:

```
Names["Language`*Mutation*"]

{"Language`HandleMutation", "Language`HasMutationHandlerQ", \
"Language`MutationFallthrough", "Language`SetMutationHandler"}
```

Does anyone we know that they do?

---

Side note: I recall a question where the OP wanted exactly this type of behavior a few years ago, but couldn't find it. Anyone know what it was called?