# Change value in a Dataset

Tags: dataset

I could not find an answer on this fundamental question, even though I was reading the references on `Dataset` and `Association` and browsing through the board. I want to use `Dataset`as a data base with changing data for the sake of readability of the code. To get a value by f["two","a"] is more associative for the reader than f[[2,2]], especially if the number of rows of f and the meaning of the rows change. I have the following data:

```
f = Dataset[<|
   "one" -> <|"a" -> Quantity [20, "Hour"], 
     "b" -> Quantity[0.5, "Hour"]|>, 
   "two" -> <|"a" -> Quantity [8, "Hour"], "b" -> Quantity[2, "Hour"]|>|>]
```

and need to change for instance the "b" value of row "two" to a new value. At best in a readable form. My guess was
`f["two","b"]=new;` but this does not work. I also tried `Replace`but also could not get it working.

Comment: related: [Error changing Dataset using Part](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/52414/142)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ReplacePart[]` works:

```
ReplacePart[f, {"two", "b"} -> Quantity[10, "Minutes"]]
```

I don't know how efficient this is if you're doing multiple changes, however.

Answer (score 0):

With the link of WReach if found that this works as well:

```
f[{"two" -> (<|#, "b" -> Quantity [0, "Hour"]|> &)}]
```

However, for the sake of code readability I favour J.M.'s answer.