# Association and rudimentary object-oriented programming

Tags: programming, associations

Doesn't `Association` provide us rudimentary object oriented programming via constructs like

```
TEST = Association["value" -> 2, "method" -> Function[{x}, x^2]]
```

> ```
> <|"value" -> 2, "method" -> Function[{x}, x^2]|>
> ```

```
TEST["value"] = TEST["method"][TEST["value"]];
TEST
```

> ```
> <|"value" -> 4, "method" -> Function[{x}, x^2]|>
> ```

Do any of you familiar with *Mathematica* syntax and details see ways to extend this theme to include inheritance and other features of OO?

Is anyone attending the *Wolfram conference* next week who would like to discuss?

Regards
Tom Gladd

Comment: I have discussed this topic a bit in [my post on the use of Associations](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52393/how-to-make-use-of-associations/54493#54493), and also [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16869/once-more-on-object-orientation-in-mathematica-does-it-have-to-be-so-hard) (not in the context of Associations). I you search this site, and also Wolfram Mathematica tag on Stack Overflow, you will find many more OO-related discussions.

Comment: OO-programming was one of the things the very first books on *Mathematica* tackled, and then it became forgotten somehow. *The Mathematica Programmer* (Maeder, 1994) devotes a chapter to OO-programming in *Mathematica*, and so does *Mastering Mathematica* (Gray, 1996). `Association` on the other hand is new since of this summer, it is approximately twenty years younger than those books...

Answer (score 2):

You could already do this with `DownValues`

```
TEST["value"] = 2;
TEST["method"] = Function[{x}, x^2];
Definition[TEST]
```

> `TEST[method] = Function[{x}, x^2]`
>
> `TEST[value] = 2`

```
TEST["value"] = TEST["method"][TEST["value"]];
Definition[TEST]
```

> `TEST[method] = Function[{x}, x^2]`
>
> `TEST[value] = 4`

This method might be easier and more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Associations (also knows as dictionaries) are essentially all that is needed for a crude class system (real men use structs, of course), and this is quite explicit in Python. However, using JUST dictionaries (or associations) without any syntactic sugar will produce extremely ugly (not to mention slow, but sugar won't help the latter problem) code.