# How to organize code for simulating many ODEs?

Tags: differential-equations, simulation, data-structures

I have a large model with many variables (about a hundred) and many differential equations (non-linear). What is the best way to handle a system this size in Mathematica?

Note that I am not asking about performance (100 variables is not that much). My concern is with handling the code in a manageable way. Each variable and each equation has a meaning and some particular structure.

If I were doing this in another language, I would create structs or types to hold different groups of properties together. But in Mathematica I have no idea how to handle the complexity.

Is there a recommended way to handle large systems of ODEs in Mathematica in an structured fashion?

Comment: "with many variables" sounds like a job for indexed variables.

Comment: @J.M. Can you expand?

Comment: I'm afraid currently the question is a bit too broad. It's hard to give useful advice without a specific example. Anyway, are you looking for [OOP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16869/1871)?

Comment: @xzczd I understand the question is somewhat broad. I am not really sure what I am looking for. OOP could be an option, but it doesn't have to be so sophisticated (inheritance is definitely overkill here). I am just looking for a simple way to structure the code of a large system of ODEs.

Comment: I've used things like `vars = Array[x, 100];`, and for time dependence in ODEs, `varst = #[t] & /@ vars; varsdt = D[varst, t]`. Not saying that's a _good_ way of doing it, but it did get the job done. If you can make your question more specific, I'd be interested in seeing the answers.

Comment: @aardvark2012 The problem is that I cannot lump all the variables together in an array. I need to refer to each of them individually by name.

Comment: "I need to refer to each of them individually by name." - so, you have 100 named variables already?

Comment: Well, you can get at them with `vars[[n]]` and the like, and use them just as you would named variables. Sure, they're not particularly _descriptive_ names, but they're just as accessible. If that's really not enough, there might be something you could do with an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html).

Comment: @J.M. Yes, as well as the equations connecting those variables. Actually it's not just me, we are a small team. But it is very unmanageable.