# Is there a method to enumerate the keys/values of System`Utilities`HashTable

Tags: programming, data-structures, undocumented

Lacking from the simple API of `` System`Utilities`HashTable `` is a method to enumerate the keys/values.

```
?System`Utilities`Hash*

HashTable   HashTableAdd    HashTableContainsQ  HashTableGet    HashTableRemove
```

After creating a hash table

```
h = System`Utilities`HashTable[];
System`Utilities`HashTableAdd[h, "a", 1];
```

Various methods to extract its content fail.

```
h[[1]]
h
DownValues[h]
```

Any way out?

Comment: I wonder what `HashTableGet[]` does... :)

Comment: @J. M. I think OP wants to list all available key-value pairs in the table, which I believe is not possible.

Comment: If you want to be able to enumerate the contents, you're probably better off just to use ordinary downvalues rather than the `System\`Utilities\`HashTable`.

Comment: Just to follow up on J. M., you have tried ``System`Utilities`HashTableGet[h, "a"]``?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm sure there must be a better way, but this works:

```
h = System`Utilities`HashTable[];
System`Utilities`HashTableAdd[h, "a", 1];
System`Utilities`HashTableAdd[h, "b", 2];

ToExpression[ToString[h, InputForm], InputForm, Hold][[1, 2]]
```

> ```
> {{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}}
> ```

Mr. Wizard provides a more terse version:

```
ToHeldExpression[ToString[h, InputForm]][[1, 2]]
```

Comment: Unless there is something like `SparseArray[. . .]["NonzeroPositions"]` for `HashTable` there very well may not be a better way.

Comment: More terse: `ToHeldExpression[ToString[h, InputForm]][[1, 2]]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, good tip, thanks. I don't think I've ever come across `ToHeldExpression` before.

Comment: As with many things *Mathematica* I [learned it from Leonid.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6236264/618728)  It's an old function but still entirely, well, functional.

Comment: +1. I still hope there is some more robust way though, since `ToString`-`ToExpression` transformation is not always robust.

Comment: @Leonid for testing purposes can you give an example where Simon's method fails?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Take any object for which `ToString` leads to a loss of information. For example, `ToExpression[
 ToString[Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3,  3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}]]]`.

Comment: @Leonid not the best example for v7. ;-)

Comment: @Leonid A rather late reply but does this address your concern, or not?: `ToHeldExpression[ToString[FullForm@h, InputForm]][[1, 1, 2]]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Conceptually, no, because every time we use the `ToString` - `ToExpression` cycle, we in some sense leave and then re-enter the execution environments. `ToString` does some sort of serialization, and `ToExpression` does the parsing. Neither of these should really be involved. In other words, we never know for which objects this may break.

Comment: @Leonid Okay, conceptually I see what you mean.  For *most* things would the `FullForm` be equivalent?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Re - most things - I really don't know. If it doesn't work for even just one, it's no good for me, for a thing as fundamental as a hash-table. Such a bug would be extremely hard to catch in a large application.

Comment: @Leonid Wise words about nasty corner cases.  Forget about the close vote.

Answer (score 13):

**OP's question**

Updating this post, the set of functions related to HashTable is in version `10.2`:

```
$ContextPath = Prepend[$ContextPath, "System`Utilities`"];
?*HashTable*

HashTable      HashTableContainsQ   HashTableMapAt    HashTableSet
HashTableAdd   HashTableGet         HashTableRemove
```

and is extended in version `10.3` to:

```
?*HashTable*

HashTable             HashTableGet      HashTableRemove
HashTableAdd          HashTableKeys     HashTableSet
HashTableClone        HashTableMapAt    HashTableToAssociation
HashTableContainsQ    HashTableQ        HashTableValues
```

With `10.3`, an easier way to extract keys/values, per OP's question, becomes available.

• Define a hash table and fill it in (`10.2`, `10.3`):

```
h = HashTable[];
HashTableAdd[h, "g", 1]
HashTableAdd[h, "h", "hello"]
```

• Extract keys and values (`10.3`):

```
HashTableKeys[h]
HashTableValues[h]

(* {"h", "g"} *)
(* {"hello", 1} *)
```

• Make it an association (`10.3`) and use the functions `Keys` and `Values`:

```
asso = HashTableToAssociation[h]
(* <|"h" -> "hello", "g" -> 1|> *)

Keys[asso]
Values[asso]

(* {"h", "g"} *)
(* {"hello", 1} *)
```

---

**What do other functions do?**

This question has been covered to some extent in other posts (in particular, see the answer of [Oleksandr R.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/312/oleksandr-r) in [post #990](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/990/struct-equivalent-in-mathematica/1029#1029)). I recall below the definitions already addressed, and provide those that are new from 10.2.

• `HashTableSet` changes the value of a key (`10.2`, `10.3`):

```
HashTableSet[h, "h", "world"];
HashTableToAssociation[h]
(* <|"h" -> "world", "g" -> 1|> *)
```

• `HashTableRemove` removes a pair key/value by referring to the key (`10.2`, `10.3`):

```
HashTableRemove[h, "h"]
(* "world" *)

HashTableToAssociation[h]
(* <|"g" -> 1|> *)
```

• `HashTableGet` gets the value of a key (`10.2`, `10.3`):

```
HashTableGet[h, "g"]
(* 1 *)
```

• `HashTableContainsQ` asks whether a key belongs to the hash table (`10.2`, `10.3`):

```
HashTableContainsQ[h, "g"]
(* True *)
```

• `HashTableMapAt` maps at a key a function on its associated value (`10.2`, `10.3`):

```
HashTableToAssociation[h]
(* <|"g" -> 1|> *)

(* when existing *)
HashTableMapAt[h, "g", foo];
HashTableToAssociation[h]
(* <|"g" -> foo[1]|> *)

(* when not existing *)
HashTableMapAt[h, "h", "hello", "world"];
HashTableToAssociation[h]
(* <|"h" -> "hello"["world"], "g" -> foo[1]|> *)
```

• `HashTableClone` clones a hash table and set it to a new one (`10.3`):

```
h2 = HashTableClone[h];
HashTableToAssociation[h2]
(* <|"h" -> "hello"["world"], "g" -> foo[1]|> *)
```

This function is particularly useful to avoid the following:

```
h3 = h;
HashTableToAssociation[h3]
(* <|"h" -> "hello"["world"], "g" -> foo[1]|> *)

HashTableAdd[h, "f", a]
HashTableToAssociation[h]
HashTableToAssociation[h2]
HashTableToAssociation[h3]

(* <|"f" -> a, "h" -> "hello"["world"], "g" -> foo[1]|> *)
(* <|"h" -> "hello"["world"], "g" -> foo[1]|> *)
(* <|"f" -> a, "h" -> "hello"["world"], "g" -> foo[1]|> *)
```

• `HashTableQ` asks whether a given expression has a hash table structure (`10.3`):

```
HashTableQ[h2]
(* True *)
```

---

**Hash tables and associations**

Associations are introduced since version `10.0`, so in principle one should prefer using them rather than hash tables. When there is a correspondence between an association function and a hash table function, the syntax of the former allows in general for more manipulations. Note also that more functions are available to manipulate associations.

Here is an equivalence between hash table and association functions (recall that `` "System`Utilities`" `` has been added in the context path):

```
(* Hash tables: *)    HashTableKeys
(* Associations: *)   Keys

(* Hash tables: *)    HashTableValues
(* Associations: *)   Values

(* Hash tables: *)    HashTableRemove
(* Associations: *)   KeyDrop

(* Hash tables: *)    HashTableGet
(* Associations: *)   Lookup, asso[key], asso[[Key[key]]]

(* Hash tables: *)    HashTableAdd
(* Associations: *)   Association[asso, key -> value]

(* Hash tables: *)    HashTableSet
(* Associations: *)   asso[key] = ..., asso[[Key[key]]] = ...

(* Hash tables: *)    HashTableClone
(* Associations: *)   asso1 = asso2

(* Hash tables: *)    HashTableContainsQ
(* Associations: *)   KeyExistsQ
```

Comment: Nice answer! Are you sure you want it to be a community wiki?  It will probably get a fair number of votes. :-)

Comment: I searched for documentation of HashTable functions on the web and on the help system of Mathematica 10.3. They are not documented, they exist only in System'Utilities. Is there any reason one should prefer to use HashTable instead of Association ?

Comment: @Athanassios (1/3) I would not recommend using HashTable instead of Association. The main reason is that, as you mentioned, the functions related to HashTable are not documented and not in System. So there is no guarantee that these functions won't change, or won't crash the kernel for some particular inputs. (I think these functions are robust, but this is always to keep in mind however for non-documented functions.)

Comment: @Athanassios (2/3)  Also because not documented, their behavior can be less predictable in appearance. Compare for instance the order of the key-value pairs of `AssociationThread[# -> #] &[Range[10]]` and `h = HashTable[];
HashTableAdd[h, #, #] & /@ Range[10];
Through[{HashTableKeys, HashTableValues}[h]]` on the one hand, and the order of the latter and `g = HashTable[];
HashTableAdd[g, #, #] & /@ Range[100];
Through[{HashTableKeys, HashTableValues}[g]]` on the other. If not careful about this, issues will occur for some types of processing done on the resulting expression.

Comment: @Athanassios (3/3) About performance, the Association functions are highly optimized, so I don't think this should be a parameter to consider. At last, the Association framework contains more functions than the HashTable framework, so it will be possible to carry out more types of processing with associations.