# Matrix/tensor addition behaving funny under replacement?

Tags: matrix, replacement, tensors

I have two matrices I want to add, and one of the matrices is a tensor product of two vectors. I've used a SetDelayed to define the summed matrix, because I want to evaluate it for different values of these vectors. However, when I try to evaluate it using a replacement, I get a new array with the wrong dimensionality. Here's a minimal(ish?) example:

```
mat := DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1, 1, 1}] + TensorProduct[vec, vec]
```

Then using a replace gives me something horrible:

```
mat /. vec -> {2, 2, 2, 2}

{{{{5, 5, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 5, 5}}, {{4, 4, 4,
 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}}, {{4, 4, 4, 4}, {4,
 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}}, {{4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 
4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}}}, {{{4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 
4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}}, {{5, 5, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 5, 5}, {5, 
5, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 5, 5}}, {{4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 
4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}}, {{4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 
4, 4, 4}}}, {{{4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 
4}}, {{4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 
4}}, {{5, 5, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 5, 
5}}, {{4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 
4}}}, {{{4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 
4}}, {{4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 
4}}, {{4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 
4}}, {{5, 5, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 5, 5}, {5, 5, 5, 5}}}}
```

But a block (or setting vec={2,2,2,2}) gives the correct behavior:

```
Block[{vec = {2, 2, 2, 2}}, mat]

{{5, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 5, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 5, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 5}}
```

(Sorry, not sure if I typed in the output correctly here.)

What's going on?

Comment: The way to debug this type of problem is to evaluate your expression (`DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1, 1, 1}] + TensorProduct[vec, vec]`) symbolically.  Try that and you'll see exactly what's going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to debug this type of problem is to evaluate your expression (`DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1, 1, 1}] + TensorProduct[vec, vec]`) symbolically. Try that and you'll see exactly what's going wrong.

Addition auto-threads inside of arrays, i.e. `{1,2,3} + a` auto-evaluates to `{1 + a, 2 + a, 3 + a}`.  This is what happens in your case, with the diagonal matrix standing in place of `{1,2,3}`, and the still symbolic `TensorProduct[vec, vec]` in place of `a`.

You could use

```
DiagonalMatrix[diag] + TensorProduct[vec, vec]  /. {diag -> {1,1,1,1}, vec -> {2,2,2,2}}
```

or

```
Hold[DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1, 1, 1}] + TensorProduct[vec, vec]] /. vec -> {2,2,2,2} // ReleaseHold
```

or

```
mat[vec_] := DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1, 1, 1}] + TensorProduct[vec, vec]
```

Comment: Thanks @Szabolcs! This makes perfect sense. What I've ended up doing is defining the added matrix as above, but then assigning a value to vec before ever evaluating the addition. Is there anything especially wrong or problematic about that solution?

Comment: @Adam Do you mean doing `mat := DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1, 1, 1}] + TensorProduct[vec, vec]` then `vec = ...; mat`?  If so, it works, but I'm a bit uncomfortable as it's error-prone.  If you set the value of `vec` once only, then I'd rather do `vec = ...; mat = ...` (note `=` vs `:=`).  If you keep changing the value of `vec`, then I'd do `mat[vec_] := ...` to make it a parameter.  Sometimes I end up with several parameters that originated from global variables. In that case I sometimes use `withRules` described [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/993/12).

Comment: That is essentially an equivalent of the `Block` solution you show with the difference that it is easy to store parameter values in lists as `{vec -> ...}` and re-use them later.

Comment: The real problem is that it only works when you actually can do the replacements before. but sometimes (when generating compilation bodies e.g.) you cannot. I find this a design omittance. See also remarks [here]. (http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15676082#15676082) and [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15741740#15741740) It is always a hassle to work around the missing abstract datatype features of Mathematica (and even the Wolfram Language).