# Data Type that can contain multiple data types

Tags: data, data-types

In MATLAB one can use cell arrays and structures to "hold" data of different types.  For example, one can define a cell array in which the first cell contains an array, the second a differently sized array, the third a string, etc.  Similar things can be done with the structure data type.

Do these or similar exist in Mathematica?

Comment: related question: [Struct equivalent in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/990/9490)

Comment: As stated by @JohnDoty:  *Mathematica* does not need to employ data types.

Answer (score 2):

*Mathematica* doesn't need such a thing. "Everything is an expression." In many cases, subexpressions may be of a variety of types. Consider `List`. Any element of a list may be of any "type" you wish. `List` is basically a passive "wrapper", but even active things can wrap combinations of types. Consider:

```
1+"a string"
```

which simply fails to evaluate. `Plus` doesn't have a rule that applies to such a construct, so it becomes a passive wrapper here.