# Efficient manipulation of Associations passed to functions, how-to?

Tags: performance-tuning, programming

I have some data wrapped into a `MyData[data_Association]` "structure".

My `Association` contains some big arrays and I do not want to copy them each time I modify it.

By example, if I want to add a field, does the following code

```
foo[MyData[data_Association]] :=
  Block[{datacpy},
   datacpy = data;
   datacpy["extraField"] = 1;
   Return[MyData[datacpy]];
   ];

data=<|"bigArray"->{{}}|>; (* {{}} not empty in real situation! *)

foo[MyData[data]]
```

> MyData[<|"bigArray" -> {{}}, "extraField" ->
>   1|>]

copy the "bigArray" field even if it is not modified? (or does it use some binding/reference mechanism).

Comment: Maybe store the associations not in an array but in a dictionary? (like `dict[key]=key->value`) and store dictionary globally?

Comment: I find the "wrapping" trick `SomeSymbol[data...]` very useful and I wanted to keep using this simple approach. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I feel this is a dupe, but feel free to object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're asking whether the `foo` operation will store two independent copies of the big array. That is, given:

```
MemoryInUse[]
ds = MyData @ Association["BigArray"->RandomReal[1,10^8]];
MemoryInUse[]
```

> 42312736
>
> 842355744

Will your foo operation basically double the memory in use? Here is your `foo` function (rewritten to eliminate the superfluous [`Return`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Return) that should never be used at the end of a [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module) or [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block)):

```
foo[MyData[data_Association]] := Block[{datacpy = data},
    datacpy["extraField"] = 1;
    MyData[datacpy]
]
```

Then:

```
MemoryInUse[]
foo[ds];
MemoryInUse[]
```

> 845119768
>
> 845122344

I think the above shows that the answer is no.

Comment: I feel really uncomfortable not knowing about Return[] usage -> I just found this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58059/when-must-i-use-the-return-function Hopefully for my mood the post starts with "Return is surprisingly under-documented"

Comment: `Return` is almost useless. It isn't really under-documented, but if you expect it to be like "return" in other languages, you'll find nothing to support such usage.

Comment: @JohnDoty thanks, this is indeed the trap I fell into.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a method you could use if you really want to directly modify your association yourself. To do that, you need to store the association in a variable and use `Hold` attributes to prevent it from evaluating. In your case, it seems like it's easiest to just make `MyData` `HoldFirst`:

```
SetAttributes[MyData, HoldFirst]
```

You can now define your function as:

```
foo[MyData[data_Symbol?AssociationQ]] := (
  data["extraField"] = 1;
  MyData[data]
);
```

The `AssociationQ` pattern test will ensure that the symbol `data` refers to an association. You can use the function like so:

```
actualData = <|"bigArray" -> {{}}|>;
foo[MyData[actualData]]
actualData
```

> Out[15]= MyData[actualData]
>
> Out[16]= <|"bigArray" -> {{}}, "extraField" -> 1|>

Note that `MyData[actualData]` does not show the association because of the `HoldFirst` attribute. You could define [custom formatting rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningOutputFormats.html) to make it show a preview of the data. You could also try to turn `MyData` into a sort of constructor that will automatically create a new symbol to hold an association for you. For example:

```
ClearAll[MyData]
SetAttributes[MyData, HoldFirst]
MyData[stuff : Except[_Symbol]] := With[{
    evaluatedStuff = stuff
  },
   Module[{storeVar = evaluatedStuff},
     MyData[storeVar]
   ] /; AssociationQ[evaluatedStuff]
 ];
MyData[AssociationThread[Range[10], RandomReal[1, 10]]]
First[%]
```

> MyData[storeVar$6198]
>
> <|1 -> 0.236334, 2 -> 0.354161, 3 -> 0.314371, 4 -> 0.738186, 
>        5 -> 0.916299, 6 -> 0.0289776, 7 -> 0.831803, 8 -> 0.533609, 
>        9 -> 0.316124, 10 -> 0.211526|>

All of this is roughly how `Association` itself actually works. Note the attributes on `Association`:

```
In[29]:= Attributes[Association]
```

> {HoldAllComplete, Protected}

This is what is meant when people say that `Association` is a constructor and a container. You can tell that some sort of construction step takes place when you define an association:

```
Unevaluated[<||>] === <||>
```

> False

Comment: very interesting and clearly explained, thanks

Comment: If you are interested, I asked a related question here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/198105/42847

Comment: You can be even slicker with this (rather than just checking for a `Symbol`) but checking for the `NoEntry` or `Valid` bits. These give you a way to build a constructor that can even take a `Symbol` as input and check that this is an `Association` in a very clean and efficient way. These bits can also be applied all over the place to tell that you have a proper constructed object and not just something that syntactically matches. That's a powerful property to have.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how you want to do the modification. In general, Mathematica is actually very efficient about handling pass-by-value calls. If you look at memory consumption `"bigArray"` will not be copied:

```
struct[] :=
  struct[<||>];
struct[a_]@"Add"[field_ , val_] :=
  struct[Append[a, field -> val]];
struct[a_]@"Modify"[field_ , fn_] :=
  struct[ReplacePart[a, field -> fn@a[field]]];

myStruct = struct[];

Block[{arr = RandomReal[{}, {500, 500}]},
 (* done to prevent the memory getting stuck to Out *)
 myStruct = myStruct@"Add"["bigArray", arr];
 {arr // ByteCount, memPrev = MemoryInUse[]}
 ]

{2000152, 974574520}

Block[{},
 (* done to prevent the memory getting stuck to Out *)
 myStruct = myStruct@"Add"["empty", None];
 MemoryInUse[] - memPrev
 ]

3472
```

And in fact `"bigArray"` is really stored as an object with an internal ID as can be seen in the many low-level functions that depend on explicit expression identity.

Of course, you could do this with a direct mutable OOP approach, too, but I won't get into that here.

Comment: By mutable OOP approach you mean something like using HoldFirst attribute etc... ?

Comment: @PicaudVincent basically. And using a `Symbol` to store state. See e.g. this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/165486/38205

Comment: If you like OOP-style programming I also have the interface package that I used for this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/195065/38205

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.