# Wrapped Association into a "structure": how to define Equal[] and what are the good practices for package dev?

Tags: programming, packages

Using a nice answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197936/42847 I got from a previous question I define:

```
ClearAll[MyData]
SetAttributes[MyData, HoldFirst]
MyData[stuff : Except[_Symbol]] := 
  With[{evaluatedStuff = stuff}, 
   Module[{storeVar = evaluatedStuff}, MyData[storeVar]] /; 
    AssociationQ[evaluatedStuff]];
```

I understand that when stuff argument is an association, a local variable is created (thanks to `Module[...]`). This part is ok, demo:

```
MyData[<|"a" -> 1|>]
```

> MyData[storeVar$7548]

Now let's say I want to compare two such structures:

**No problem here:**

```
q = <|"a" -> 1|>
MyData[q]==MyData[q]
```

> True

**A problem I understand**

```
MyData[<|"a" -> 1|>] == MyData[<|"a" -> 1|>]
```

> MyData[storeVar$7538] == MyData[storeVar$7539]

Here we use two **different** internal variables to store stuff argument and they are not evaluated because of the `HoldFirst` attribute

So I introduce an overload for the `Equal[]` operator:

```
MyData /: Equal[A_MyData, B_MyData] := First[A] == First[B]
```

and now:

```
MyData[<|"a" -> 1|>] == MyData[<|"a" -> 1|>]
```

> True

works as expected.

**Problem with `VerificationTest[]`**: now I want to do units tests:

```
VerificationTest[MyData[<|"a" -> 1|>], MyData[<|"a" -> 1|>]]
```

but I get an `TestResultObject` with **Failure** Outcome!!

**First question:** Why and how to fix that? (maybe my way to define `Equal[]` is not the right one?)

**Second question:**

More broadly speaking, when you write a MMA package using "structure" like `MyData`, what is the good practice when defining stuff like:

```
Format[MyData[a_Symbol?AssociationQ]] := "Pretty print of MyData[]"
MyData /: MyData[data_Symbol?AssociationQ][s_String] := data[[s]];
```

To put then in the *public section* or in the *private one*?

```
BeginPackage["FooPackage`"];

MyData::usage="A structure ...";


... <- Format, Equal,... Here ?

Begin["`Private`"];

... <- Or here???

End[] (*Private *)

EndPackage[];
```

Comment: Yes, it is not Equal: `Options[VerificationTest, SameTest]`

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that VerificationTest by default uses SameQ

Answer (score 3):

The reason your `VerificationTest` fails is because the default test for equality of expressions is `SameQ`, not `Equals`. `Equals` is for mathematical equality and does not always evaluate to a boolean while `SameQ` tests if expressions are literally the same:

```
ClearAll[x, y]
x == x
```

> True

```
x == y
```

> x == y

```
x === x
```

> True

```
x === y
```

> False

There are two things you can do:

1. Change the option of `SameTest`:

   `VerificationTest[MyData[<|"a" -> 1|>], MyData[<|"a" -> 1|>], SameTest -> Equal]`
2. Add an `UpValue` for `SameQ` (this is probably the best option of the two):

   `MyData /: SameQ[A_MyData, B_MyData] := First[A] == First[B];
   VerificationTest[MyData[<|"a" -> 1|>], MyData[<|"a" -> 1|>]]`

As for your second question: I would say that all definitions should go in the `Private` context, so that includes formatting rules. The part before the begin of the private section is mainly for creating the symbols you want to export from the package. This is usually done by defining the usage message for that symbol, but even that's not strictly necessary. Any mention of the symbol outside of the private context will create the symbol in the public context.

Comment: Thanks again for this clear explanation (I just realized for the SameQ vs Equal). Ok for the second question