# Is it possible to create lookups on temporary symbols that still allow the symbols to be automatically removed?

Tags: programming, clear, assignment

Is there some way to create lookups keyed on `Temporary` symbols that somehow avoid the referencing of the `Temporary` symbols, allowing the symbols and the values to still be automatically garbage collected?

```
(*$HistoryLength must be zero so that In/Out don't set up references to our symbols:*)
$HistoryLength = 0;
Names["Global`$myTemp*"]

ClearAll[CreateTemporarySymbol]

CreateTemporarySymbol[] := With[{p = Module[{pp = Unique["$myTemp", Temporary]}, pp]}, p]
```

Let's create two lists of these temp symbols. We can of course see the symbols in the **Global** context:

```
list[1] = Table[CreateTemporarySymbol[], 5]
list[2] = Table[CreateTemporarySymbol[], 5]
Names["Global`$myTemp*"]

(* -> {$myTemp3,$myTemp4,$myTemp5,$myTemp6,$myTemp7}*)
(* -> {$myTemp8,$myTemp9,$myTemp10,$myTemp11,$myTemp12}*)
(* -> {"$myTemp10","$myTemp11","$myTemp12","$myTemp3","$myTemp4","$myTemp5","$myTemp6","$myTemp7","$myTemp8","$myTemp9"}*)
```

Because the symbols were created as **Temporary**, deleting list[2] causes it's variables to be released and automatically cleaned up. Now only the symbols that are in list[1] remain:

```
list[2] =.
Names["Global`$myTemp*"]
(*-> {"$myTemp3","$myTemp4","$myTemp5","$myTemp6","$myTemp7"}*)
```

That is all the standard behavior.

Suppose, however, that I want to attach some values to these symbols. I don't want to store the values in the symbols themselves as I intend to use the symbols in many places and <s>don't want to use up memory</s> don't want the symbol to be evaluated for Printing or Saving or Cases or Select (the values might be large expressions the details of which are irrelevant to my purposes).

Is there some way of doing this that preserves their auto-cleanup when I remove the list[1] that contains them?

I had assumed that all of the DownValues/UpValues wouldn't work, but hoped that perhaps **TagSet** might.

Alas, it does not:

```
ClearAll[TryToHideSomeValues]

TryToHideSomeValues[myTemp_, value_] := With[{p = myTemp}, p /: HiddenValue[p] = value]

MapThread[TryToHideSomeValues[#1, #2] &, {list[1], RandomReal[{1, 11}, {5, 5}]}]

Map[HiddenValue, list[1]]

(* -> {{8.971, 5.41, 10.13, 8.482, 1.743}, {9.795, 7.289, 10.06, 1.640, 8.272}, {4.788, 5.803, 7.973, 6.589, 2.513}, {9.007, 2.325, 8.298, 7.071, 6.16}, {9.037, 3.004, 2.911, 8.603, 8.603}} *)
```

Naturally this is because **TagSet** is no different from anyone else in this regard and also registers any symbols on its LHS: deleting list[1] does not allow its symbols to get automatically released, as it had for list[2]:

```
list[1] =.
Names["Global`$myTemp*"]

(* -> {"$myTemp3","$myTemp4","$myTemp5","$myTemp6","$myTemp7"}*)
```

**Is there some magic spot that one might hide such values such that the symbols *and the values* still get cleaned when list[1] is deleted?**

I have looked around SE and seen e.g. 'Weak hash maps' and  **Language`NewExpressionStore** which might somehow be solutions, but nothing obvious seemed to pop up.

In fact **OwnValues** does already operate in this requested fashion. Just because list[1] contains multiple copies of a symbol with OwnValues doesn't mean that the memory footprint is increased for each repetition ('laziness') - not until some sort of 'final' evaluation (like printing or saving) do the OwnValues of the symbols get inserted and expanded. So the memory storage of the values of the symbols is not the issue. It is more an issue of how a list of symbols with massive OwnValues can be saved or displayed without hassle.

---

In response to @b3m21a's very helpful answer I have made an updated version of my OP using **`NewExpressionStore`**.

It seems to me that **`NewExpressionStore`** is also incapable of providing the capabilities I desire: separation of symbols from values and the automatic deletion of symbols and values when the (`Temporary`) symbols are no longer referenced:

As before, I set up `Temporary` symbols, creating 5 of them inside `list[1]`:

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
Names["Global`$myTemp*"]

ClearAll[CreateTemporarySymbol]

CreateTemporarySymbol[] := With[{p = Module[{pp = Unique["$myTemp", Temporary]}, pp]}, p]

list[1] = Table[CreateTemporarySymbol[], 5]

-> {$myTemp3, $myTemp4, $myTemp5, $myTemp6, $myTemp7}

Names["Global`$myTemp*"]

-> {"$myTemp3", "$myTemp4", "$myTemp5", "$myTemp6", "$myTemp7"}
```

Modifying b3m21a's answer, I create `hiddenCache` which is a `NewExpressionStore` from the built-in Language` context:

```
hiddenCache = Language`NewExpressionStore["someLabel"]
```

... and 'put' a matrix directly into it:

```
hiddenCache["put"[HiddenValues, $myTemp3, {{7, 3}, {4, 9}}]]
```

The matrix is stored in the `hiddenCache`, associated with the (`Temporary`) `$myTemp3` symbol:

```
hiddenCache["get"[HiddenValues, $myTemp3]]

-> {{7, 3}, {4, 9}}
```

... but since the matrix is not stored in the OwnValues of `$myTemp3`, it doesn't get expressed when we view `list[1]` (the matrix is also untouchable by `Save` or `Cases` or any other function that might operate on `list[1]`). This achieves my first objective of separating the values from the symbols:

```
$myTemp3
list[1]

-> $myTemp3

-> {$myTemp3, $myTemp4, $myTemp5, $myTemp6, $myTemp7}
```

Of course all of the `$myTemp` vars are in the namespace:

```
Names["Global`$myTemp*"]

-> {"$myTemp3", "$myTemp4", "$myTemp5", "$myTemp6", "$myTemp7"}
```

...But because they are `Temporary`, and because `list[1]` contains their only reference, they get automatically cleaned up when we delete `list[1]`, except for `$myTemp3` which is now unfortunately bound somewhere in the `hiddenCache`:

```
list[1] =.
Names["Global`$myTemp*"]

-> {"$myTemp3"}
```

The values are still being stored in `hiddenCache`, associated with `$myTemp3`, and binding to it so that it couldn't be automatically cleaned up. This fails my second objective of having the values being automatically removed at the same time as the symbols are:

```
hiddenCache["listTable"[]]

-> {{HiddenValues, {{$myTemp3, {{7, 3}, {4, 9}}}}}}
```

The only way to get `$myTemp3` to be removed from the namespace is for `HiddenValues` to be 'removed':

```
hiddenCache["remove"[HiddenValues]]
```

Now the values that had been in `hiddenCache` are gone:

```
hiddenCache["listTable"[]]

->  {}
```

... and now `$myTemp` is truly cleaned up:

```
Names["Global`$myTemp*"]

-> {}
```

However this fails my desire of not having to do my own garbage collection.

Comment: You could use strings containing the (full) symbol names as keys...

Comment: This is exactly what [`ExpressionStore`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171154/38205) is built for.

Comment: Thanks @b3m2a1. I'll have to try out an implementation using it. As you say in your post, it does look a little clunky.

Comment: "I don't want to store the values in the symbols themselves as I intend to use the symbols in many places and don't want to use up memory (the values might be large numeric matrices)." - I don't get these memory considerations. You are probably not aware that _Mathematica_ uses lazy copying.

Comment: Yes @HenrikSchumacher you are right, I wasn't thinking clearly on this point. I subsequently edited my post to fix this. But the problem still remains for things like Print or Save which will of course 'expand' all the symbols. Also things like Cases will search all of the OwnValues too, is that right?

Comment: Thanks for the edits folks.

Comment: I've since realized that 'Atomicity' and making something 'Atomic' are a good bit of what I am asking here, and there is an extensive discussion of this in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198378/custom-atomic-expressions-modern-tutorial/198381#198381. I can't say that I understood much of it though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `OwnValues` can be abused for that.

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
CreateTemporarySymbol[] := Module[{p = Unique["$myTemp", Temporary]}, p]
AppendToOwnValues[symbol_, key_, value_] := AppendTo[OwnValues[symbol], key :> value]
ExtractOwnValue[symbol_, key_] := key /. ReleaseHold[OwnValues[symbol]]
```

Creating temporary symbols and storing values in them:

```
list[1] = Table[CreateTemporarySymbol[], 5];
MapThread[AppendToOwnValues, {list[1], ConstantArray["Key", 5], RandomReal[{1, 11}, {5, 5}]}];
```

Retrieving a value:

```
ExtractOwnValue[list[1][[1]], "Key"]
```

> {9.58016, 9.22525, 3.86703, 5.60385, 4.23212}

Deleting the list `list[1]` and checking that the symbols are really erased:

```
Names["Global`$myTemp*"]
list[1] =.
Names["Global`$myTemp*"]
```

> `{"$myTemp11", "$myTemp12", "$myTemp13", "$myTemp14", "$myTemp15"}`
>
> `{}`

However, I am pretty sure that `OwnValues` is not meant for that.

Comment: Thanks Henrik, I have used this (abusive) method and can report that it is working now without issue for many months now. I really think Wolfram should make TagSet operate in this fashion by default - that is, not having symbols referenced on the LHS of the TagSet values being referenced in the symbol dependency table.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example of how you can use `ExpressionStore` for this:

```
tempCache = Language`NewExpressionStore["ilmbiahi"];

bindTempSyms[holder_Symbol, key_, syms_] :=
  tempCache@"put"[holder, key, syms];
getTempSyms[holder_Symbol, key_] :=
  tempCache@"get"[holder, key];

Module[{list},

 Module[{sym1, sym2, sym3},
  bindTempSyms[list, 1, {Hold[sym1], Hold[sym2], Hold[sym3]}];
  sym1 = "dog";
  sym2 = "cat";
  sym3 = "my shattered hopes and dreams";
  ];

 getTempSyms[list, 1][[-1]] // ReleaseHold
 ]

"my shattered hopes and dreams"

Names["sym*"]

{"sym1", "sym1$", "sym2", "sym2$", "sym3", "sym3$", "syms"}
```

Note that the `Module`-ized versions of these symbols don't appear.

What's nice about this is whenever `list` went out of scope—even if it were returned from the `Module` (and if `list` wouldn't have been bound to `Out`)—those bound symbols would go out of scope too.

On the other hand, you indicate that your biggest issue now is in display? I'm not sure exactly what you mean there, but there are many ways to display big values compactly. The standard way is through `` BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox ``. I won't get into how it works, but there are many, many usages of it across the site. Here's how it can work with a general data structure as implemented [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/198381/38205):

```
RegisterDataStructure[
  pkg`myObj,
  pkg`myObj[Hold[sym_Symbol]]
  ];
pkg`myObj[] := Module[{tmp}, pkg`myObj@Hold[tmp]]

po = pkg`myObj[]
```

[image]

Here's how you could set the data on such an object:

```
pkg`setObjData[po, RandomReal[{}, {100, 100}]]
```

[image]

Note that the object data has changed:

```
pkg`myObj`Data@po // ReleaseHold // ByteCount

80152
```

This can be chained with `ExpressionStore` to make some very powerful encapsulation strategies.

Comment: Thanks @b3m2a1, this helps me a lot towards figuring out the NewExpressionStore syntax. I have posted an answer also with an implementation based on this answer of yours. However it still doesn't achieve what I am looking for. I have, however, changed things a bit (using the symbols as keys and not storing the Held-symbols, but the values directly), so perhaps my changes have destroyed your version's capabilities.

Comment: @berniethejet if your only remaining issues are in the *display* you can easily do that via a custom `Format` rule. Let me emphasize though that I think you might want to rethink how you’re writing this just a little bit. If something very simple (what you want to do) is becoming so convoluted and difficult, there is probably a simpler more direct path.

Comment: Thanks @b3m2a1. As everyone has pointed out, my goals weren't clearly stated. To be able to print out the list[1] without seeing the contents of the myTemp is just one part of suppressing myTemp. I also need to Save the list[i] without having the myTemp being expressed, and I operate on the list[i] in all sorts of ways with e.g. Cases which I don't want to search into the myTemp, to save time.

Answer (score 3):

You could use strings containing the (full) symbol names as keys. This function may come in handy:

```
f = Function[s,
   Context[s] <> SymbolName[Unevaluated[s]],
   HoldFirst
   ];
```

Examples:

```
a = 1;
bla`a = 2;
bla`bli`blubb`a = 2;
f[a]
f[bla`a]
f[bla`bli`blubb`a]
```

> `` "Global`a" ``
>
> `` "bla`a" ``
>
> `` "bla`bli`blubb`a" ``

Comment: Hmmm, yes, that is a good idea. I'll have to test it out. I have always worried about using the string 'interfaces' to variables as I have felt (but have yet to verify) that e.g. Names["`Global`$myTemp*'] slows down significantly the longer that MMA runs as it piles up more and more (often leaked) symbols.

Comment: The problem with this method is that I still have to do garbage collection on the DownValues of whatever lookup function I create on the stringified names, is that right?

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand your point...

Comment: Well, suppose I modified my function above to use your 'f' stringifier: TryToHideSomeValues[myTemp_, value_] := With[{p = f@myTemp}, p /: HiddenValue[p] = value]. Wouldn't I still have to do my own garbage collection on 'HiddenValue[p]'?

Comment: `p /: HiddenValue[p] = value` proablby won't work because `p` is now a string. Simply use `With[{p = f@myTemp}, HiddenValue[p] = value]`.

Comment: Right. But I'd still have to do my own garbage collection on HiddenValue[p]. Even after p-the-symbol had been automatically garbage collected, HiddenValue[p-the-string] would linger, is that right?

Comment: Yes, but I thought that _you wanted it this way_. Please double check your post and rephrase it.  I have also the very strong feeling that this is an X-Y problem. What is it what you _actually_ want to do?

Comment: Yes, you are right @HenrikSchumacher, I didn't say this at all clearly. I have added 'such that the symbols AND THE VALUES get automatically cleaned up' to my OP. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

If it is OK to use `OwnValues` and you avoid them just to prevent large expressions from appearing as output, then you can wrap the temporary symbols you create in `Hold` and release it when necessary.

For example,

```
$HistoryLength = 0;
Names["temp*"]
(*{}*)

sym = Module[
 {temp},
 temp = 1;
 Hold[temp]
]

Names["temp*"]
(*{"temp", "temp$2465"}*)

sym =.
Names["temp*"]
(*{temp}*)
```

**EDIT**

By the way, I have once faced myself a task of garbage collecting `Temporary` symbols with `DownValues`. Unfortunately, I don't have time to write a full solution at the moment, but the main idea is simple: you introduce an auxiliary `Temporary` symbol to count references to your main symbol (which now can be not `Temporary`):

```
ClearAll[reference, new]
new[] := Module[
  {ref, store},
  reference[store] ^= Context[ref] <> SymbolName[ref];
  reference[ref, store]
]
```

Now you can attach any definitions to the generated `store$123` symbol and use `reference[ref$123, store$123]` objects in your code to access them. If no `reference[ref$123, store$123]` objects are referenced any more, then `ref$123` will be released, which you can check with `Names@reference@store$123`. Of course, this approach would require to call garbage collection manually from time to time, but the benefit of calling garbage collection this way is that you can implement a finilizer which will be executed before releasing `store$123` symbol.

Comment: Alright thanks @AntonSakovich, this sounds interesting, let me try it out and get back to you.