# Is there a good reason why `Slot[]` is not an atomic expression?

Tags: core-language, map, pure-function, expression-construction, slot

Here's a good reason why I think it should be,

```
Map[ If[AtomQ@#, #->"is an atom", #->"not an atom"]&
      , {"hello",Range@3, # &}
      , {-1}
   ]
```

> During evaluation of In[9]:= Function::slot: Slot[(If[AtomQ[#1],#1->is an atom,#1-> not an atom]&)[1]] (in Slot[(If[AtomQ[#1],#1->is an atom,#1-> not an atom]&)[1]]&) should contain a non-negative integer or string.

```
Out[9]= {"hello" -> "is an atom", 
         {1 -> "is an atom", 2 -> "is an atom", 3 -> "is an atom"}, 
        Slot[(If[AtomQ[#1], #1 -> "is an atom", #1 -> " not an atom"] &)[1]] &}
```

Given that `Slot[]` is not atomic, to map a function to all atoms in an expression that contains pure functions ends up by messing up their definitions.

**Edit 1 - Another Example**:
I have this list

```
l1 = {1, Range@3, Point@{2,2}}
```

and I want to divide all numbers by two. I can do

```
Map[1/2 #&, l1, {-1}]
```

> {1/2, {1/2, 1, 3/2}, Point[{1, 1}]}

But now if instead of a Point I have a function that creates a Point

```
l2 = {1, Range@3, Point@{#1,#2}&}
```

I expect a similar result, where the argument of Point are divided by 2 i.e. `Point@{1/2 #1, 1/2 #2}`&. But given that `Slot[n]` is not an atom, that Map divides the index `n` inside `Slot[n]`  by two, which does not make sense at all

```
Map[1/2 #&, l2, {-1}]
```

> Function::slot: #((0.5 #1 & )[1]) (in Point[{#((0.5 #1 & )[1]), #((0.5 #1 >&)[2])}] & ) should contain a non-negative integer or string

Comment: I am not sure I understand why this is a good reason. You can always end up with a strange result if you don't pay attention. How about using `1&` instead of `#&`, is that result expected?

Comment: @Kuba As I said, the fact that Slot is not an atom messes up pure functions, any pure function, so `1&` instead of #1& does not solve the general problem. See my edit for further examples.

Comment: My point about `1&` was that it results in possibly an unexpected result from your code, it was not meant to solve anything. I don't have an opinion here, I just said that your example didn't convince me. Btw, take a look at this [198378](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198378/custom-atomic-expressions-modern-tutorial) thread. Among other things it discusses pros and cons of using atomic expressions.

Comment: @Kuba Now I see what you meant. Considering my edit, where I Map the division by two to all atoms in a list conaining `1&`, the latter becomes `((1*#1)/2 & )[1] & ` which is not clear what it means, but at least it does not give error insofar it does not mess with `Slot` argument (the index of Slot)

Comment: `1&` exhibits issue when you map inside expressions which have `Hold*` attributes. And `...&` (`Function`) is `HoldAll`. A quick example is `#^2& /@ Hold[1,2,3]`. So not quite related to the original `Slot` problem but also showing that Map at `{-1}` result does not need to be 'neat'.

Comment: Note, by the way, that `#` is not `Slot[]`, but `Slot[1]` as in the second example, as you can see by `# & // FullForm`. Interesting, though...I'm not sure atoms are quite what you want to map over here (if you're looking for atoms, you might not want to do it in such a way that keeps them inside their original expression, as in the first example; in the second, you might want to use a more careful `/.` instead of `Map` appropriately.)