# Making an expression to Iceberg-like object?

Tags: evaluation, string-manipulation, hold, expression

Can we construct a function **Iceberg**,
which maps a given expression X to Iceberg[X]
**satisfying 1. and 2.  and 3.** ?

**1**. From Iceberg[X],
it is not possible to inspect/extract a part of X *with usual method*.
It would be better if there is no part of Iceberg[X].
Applying Iceberg to X is like putting X into an iceberg.

ex) It is not difficult to extract 3rd part of {101,102,103,104,105},
from Hold[{101,102,103,104,105}].

```
    In[1]  Hold[{101,102,103,104,105}][[1]][[3]] 

    Out[1] 103
```

So Hold is *not* like Iceberg.

Likewise, for HoldComplete, Unevaluate, Defer, Inactivate, ... and combinations of these commands, similar method can extract any part of X.

So they are not like Iceberg.

**2**. From Iceberg[X], there is a unique way to comeback to X.

```
In[2]  Icemelt[Iceberg[{101,102,103,104,105}]]
Out[2]  {101,102,103,104,105}
```

No function other than 'Icemelt', can do it.

**3**. In fact there is a function satisfying 1. and 2. :
Iceberg = ToString
Icemelt = ToExpression

But I ask you to find another solution.

I believe ToString/ToExpression is the only solution.

Comment: "I believe ToString/ToExpression is the only solution." -- Also, [`Encrypt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Encrypt.html) / [`Decrypt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Decrypt.html).

Comment: also `Compress`/`Uncompress`?

Comment: Until a while ago, I've thought 'making expressions to a strings,
and do something(joining, splitting, ... ) to those strings,
and comeback to expressions is unnatural, ugly way of programming'.

Comment: 'I should prefer to use 
Hold, Defer, Inactivate.. 
because it looks much more professional'

Comment: But now, I think 1) convert to string  2) do something 3)back to expression
method is just good.

Comment: Because is ToString makes an expression more stable than any combination of evaluation-related built-in functions like Hold,Defer,...

Comment: **1.** Strings are easier to reason with -- they are simple structures, familiar, present in many programing languages. **2.** Because strings are simple their application is limiting. **3.** It is not clear what is your end goal. If strings let you achieve it faster or easier then use strings.

Comment: My goal was making a function whose input is a friendly readable loop pseudocode and output is actual working loop code. The method uses joining strings like "If[" or "]]]" or "Goto[" extensively.

Comment: As a user, I dislike this sort of thing, but the question has been asked and answered here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198378/custom-atomic-expressions-modern-tutorial

Comment: @b3m2a1's [`myObj[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/198381/4999) function does what `Iceberg[]` is supposed to, and we can define `Icemelt[myObj[data_]] := data` to get #2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom atomic expressions - modern tutorial](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198378/custom-atomic-expressions-modern-tutorial)

Comment: I came across this in the review queue. I did not vote to close yet, but I wanted to note that this is a very strange question without context, and I don't see how it would help any future reader. Sure, there are many functions that satisfy your conditions, as pointed out by the first few comments. Presumably you have a motivation for asking this, which should be clarified. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: In principle, one can always write an equivalent to ToExpression, Decrypt, Uncompress, BinaryDeserialize, etc. from scratch, so in this sense, they're not unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll@Iceberg;
expr : HoldPattern[Iceberg[x_]] /; ! AtomQ[Unevaluated[expr]] := 
 System`Private`SetNoEntry[Unevaluated[expr]];
Iceberg /: MakeBoxes[v_Iceberg?AtomQ, fmt_] := 
 InterpretationBox[
  RowBox[{"Iceberg", "[", "\[LeftAngleBracket]", "\[RightAngleBracket]", "]"}], v];
Icemelt[HoldPattern[Iceberg[x_]]] := x
```

Now you can do

```
Iceberg[{1,2,3}]
```

[image]

I believe it satisfies the other requirements

```
In[80]:= Iceberg[{101, 102, 103, 104, 105}][[1]][[3]]

During evaluation of In[80]:= Part::partd: Part specification Iceberg[\[LeftAngleBracket]\[RightAngleBracket]][[1]] is longer than depth of object.

During evaluation of In[80]:= Part::partw: Part 3 of Iceberg[\[LeftAngleBracket]\[RightAngleBracket]][[1]] does not exist.

Out[80]= Iceberg[{101, 102, 103, 104, 105}][[1]][[3]]

In[81]:= Icemelt[Iceberg[{101, 102, 103, 104, 105}]]

Out[81]= {101, 102, 103, 104, 105}
```

Comment: This doesn't guard you from pattern matching in general, so IceMelt is not unique: `Replace[Iceberg[{1,2,3}],Verbatim[Iceberg][x_]:>x]`. I'm looking for something similar, that also prevents anyone from looking at insides with pattern matching, but everything is still visible in `InputForm`. Like `Graph`, I don't understand how graph works, it is AtomQ, EntryQ, and without WXF type, but it prevents looking inside of it with every other means, without some BinarySerialize/BinaryDeserialize like hacks of course.

Comment: @swish - I am not aware of any method to do what you want without implementing it in the kernel C code, like Graph.

Answer (score 2):

Silly, but fun

```
X = {101, 102, 103, 104, 105};

img = Rasterize[X];

ToExpression[TextRecognize[img]] === X
(* True *)
```

Comment: This is, great :) I was thinking that it will be an interesting challenge to list or enumerate all possible ways to do the "icebergs" in WL.

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to come close to satisfying all the properties, including Icemelt uniqueness. I don't know any method to hack this `Iceberg` at this point, but I'll think about it more. If someone knows a hack please let me know:

```
(* hold attribute helpers *)

HoldPosition[sym_Symbol[args___]] := With[{attrs = Attributes[sym], len = Length @ Unevaluated @ {args}},
    Which[
        MemberQ[attrs, HoldFirst],
        {1},
        MemberQ[attrs, HoldRest],
        Range[2, len],
        MemberQ[attrs, HoldAll | HoldAllComplete],
        Range @ len,
        True,
        {}
    ]
]

HoldPosition[_] := Missing["Position"]

HoldPositionQ[expr_, i_] := With[{pos = HoldPosition[Unevaluated[expr]]}, MissingQ[pos] || MemberQ[pos, i]]

SequenceHoldQ[sym_Symbol[___]] := MemberQ[Attributes[sym], SequenceHold]
SequenceHoldQ[_] := False


(* Icemelt *)

(* always melt with StackComplete  *)
Icemelt[Verbatim[Iceberg][data_]] /; MemberQ[Stack[], StackComplete] := data
Icemelt[iceberg_Iceberg] := StackComplete[Icemelt[iceberg]]
Icemelt[expr___] := $Failed


(* Iceberg *)

Iceberg::unbrk = "is unbreakable with ``";
Iceberg::symbol = "attempt at reading iceberg symbol is detected";

(* run this if anything except Icemelt is executed with Iceberg in it *)
Iceberg /: expr : (f : Except[Icemelt])[left___, iceberg_Iceberg, right___] /; ! SequenceHoldQ[Unevaluated[expr]] :=
With[{
    i = Length[HoldComplete[left]] + 1
},
    (
        Message[Iceberg::unbrk, HoldForm[DisableFormatting[f[left, Iceberg["\[Ellipsis]"], right]]]];
        $Failed
    ) /; ! HoldPositionQ[Unevaluated[expr], i]
]

(* formatting *)
Iceberg /: MakeBoxes[iceberg_Iceberg, fmt___] := With[{data = StackComplete @ Icemelt[iceberg]},
    BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox["Iceberg", "Iceberg"["\[Ellipsis]"], Style["", 48], {{}}, {{data}}, fmt]
]

(* make Iceberg atomic *)
Iceberg /: iceberg_Iceberg /; System`Private`HoldEntryQ[iceberg] := System`Private`HoldSetNoEntry[iceberg]

(* make an Iceberg with protected symbol that only returns its data inside Icemelt *)
iceberg : Iceberg[data_] /; System`Private`HoldNotValidQ[iceberg] := Module[{var},
    var := If[MemberQ[Stack[], Icemelt], data, Message[Iceberg::"symbol"]; $Failed];
    SetAttributes[var, {Protected, ReadProtected, Locked}];
    System`Private`HoldSetValid[Iceberg[var]]
]

(* protect and lock it *)
SetAttributes[Iceberg, {ReadProtected, Protected, Locked, HoldAllComplete}]
```

Here is notebook with an example: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/nikm/Published/Iceberg.nb

Comment: This seems interesting as an academic exercise only.  You can't even put your object inside a list without it complaining: `{Iceberg[{1, 2, 3}], Iceberg[{1, 2, 3}]}`. I think you would have a hard time doing anything useful with it

Comment: @JasonB. That's perfectly ok, it's intended to be held. You gotta support your iceberg by holding it at all costs :)

Comment: @JasonB. Also a relaxation can be made with an additional condition `ValueQ[Unevaluated[expr]]` that will allow pure structural modification like wrapping lists and other symbols around icebergs.