# Type formation rules for 1-position expressions

Tags: symbolic, pattern-matching, core-language, symbols, data-types

I made a summary of the rules for formation of types for simple 1-position expressions, as I understand them.

Here it is in textual form:

- A symbol, say, α, is a discrete entity, represented by a unique string of characters
- A type is created from a symbol, or from another type, with the operator `[]` (column **Type**, downwards in the table)
- In the other "direction" (upwards in the table, column **Head**), the head of a type is an operation of reading a label, in the form of a symbol, from an expression. Despite being "in the other direction", it is not a dual of creating a type, as creating a type returns an expression, and reading a head returns a symbol.
- So, for example: the head of `x[][]` is `x[]`, the head of `x[]` is `x`, etc.. On the other direction, adding `[]` to `x` creates a type `x[]`, to `x[]` creates a type `x[][]`, and so on.
- The head of a symbol without brackets `x` is the symbol `Symbol`, common head of all symbols without brackets
- The head of `Symbol` is also just `Symbol` itself, so, in a way, `Symbol` is the "root" symbol of the "hierarchy"
- Being a "root", a type is exceptionally created from `Symbol` by also specifying its identifying string: `Symbol["name"]`, which is the symbol `name`.

Here is a table representation:

| Expression | Head ↑ | Type ↓ |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | … |  |
| `Symbol` | `Symbol` | `α` |
| `α` | `Symbol` | `α[]` |
| `α[]` | `α` | `α[][]` |
| `α[][]` | `α[]` | `α[][][]` |
|  | … |  |

Are these rules correct?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your table is necessarily incorrect, but I don't think it's the best way to think about it. In Mathematica, [everything is an expression](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Expressions.html) (see the linked tutorial for more details). Every<sup>1</sup> expression is one  of two things:

- Atomic: Things like numbers, symbols, etc. `AtomQ[expr]` returns `True`, and the head is not necessarily "part" of the expression: `Head[x]` is `Symbol`, `Head[1]` is `Integer`, etc.

  - Symbols have a name and context, retrievable by [`SymbolName`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SymbolName.html) and [`Context`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Context.html), respectively. A symbol can be created from its textual representation using [`Symbol`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Symbol.html) or [`ToExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html), where the latter also works for all other types, e.g. integers. The "exceptional" behavior of creating new symbols using `Symbol` is more of a convenient "overload" of the symbol `Symbol` rather than a deeper property in my mind. For example, `Rational[3/4]` will return `3/4`, which has head `Rational` (but `Integer[3]` is not `3`).
- Composite: Everything else. The form is `head[arg1,…]`, where each of `head`, `arg1`,… can themselves be any expression (of course, there can also be no arguments). `AtomQ[head[…]]` returns `False`, `Head[head[…]]` returns `head`<sup>2</sup>.

*Side note*: I don't really know what you mean with "type" but it is not commonly used when talking about Mathematica.

<sup>1</sup>There are some subtleties regarding stuff like [`` System`Private`SetNoEntry ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198378/custom-atomic-expressions-modern-tutorial), but ignore that for now

<sup>2</sup>If the expression is not evaluated further