# Elegant way to validate expression?

Tags: expression-test, expression-construction

Suppose I'm using the expression `Person[fn_String, ln_String]` as a data expression, and want to prohibit the creation of expressions where `PersonQ[person]` is `False`.

Q: Is there an "elegant" way to implement this?

Attempts:

1. I can create an additional function, say, `CreatePerson[fn_String, ln_String]` that only returns the `Person` expression if `PersonQ` is `True`. This does not prevent the creation of arbitrary `Person` expressions. Also, this feels like I'm missing something obvious.
2. I've tried defining `Person` to be a function and return `Person[fn,ln]` as a deferred evaluation expression, but the head of this expression is not `Person`. That is, the `FullForm` is not `Person[fn,ln]`.  Not ideal...
3. I've created a `Person[fn,ln]` function that creates a String `s="Person[fn,ln]"` and then returns `ToExpression[s]`, but this feels extremely hacky.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: How about: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/198532/5478?

Comment: @Kuba Thank you! This is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think that #1 is the way to go. There may be more contextual info to consider, but my suggestion is based on just what I can glean from your question. You can make this even more rigorous by using a "private" context. Let's say you're building a package. Maybe the package context is Stuff. You'd publicly declare CreatePerson (or NewPerson, or whatever), but the head of the thing returned would actually be in a specific context different from Global (which is where the user is probably operating). Maybe Stuff'Private'Person (those should be backticks, but I don't know how to make backticks visible here). You'd also have to publish the functions that operate on Stuff'Private'Person "objects". Nothing in Mathematica is truly private, but this is typically a sufficient degree of "private-ness". The users do things like `myPerson = CreatePerson[fn, ln]`, and thereafter they just operate on `myPerson`, so they don't ever need to know the actual head of the expression (but if they want to, they can still muck stuff up--they just have to be very deliberate about it, and in that case caveat emptor).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply!  After exploring patterns some more, I did find another approach that I'm happy with.

- I created a `PersonQ[args_List]` function.
- For the `Person` expression, I then added validation using `Person[args__/;!PersonQ[{args}]]:=Messages[Person::error];`

This way the `Person` expression is created if it passes all the validation rules, while an error message is displayed otherwise.

Comment: I don't think this is a good way to go (but maybe something got lost in translation). First off, `Messages` is a built in function that expects a symbol. So the thing you're returning here is an overload of a semantically different thing.

Comment: But maybe you meant `Message` (without the "s"). It's fine to emit a message like that, but what happens with `Message` is that it puts the message in the message "system" (I don't know what to call it) but the value it returns is Null. So, that accomplishes your goal, but it does it very aggressively. Having Nulls popping up spontaneously in other expressions could have unexpected (undesirable) consequences.

Comment: This is very different than the way Mathematica behaves for system functions. Try `Sin[1,2]`. That's an unhandled form for Sin, and as one might expect, it generates a message. But it still returns the expression `Sin[1,2]`.

Comment: Thank you for comments! I did use `Message` and not `Messages` - twas a typo. Returning `Null` is definitely a problem.  And that's an excellent point that returning `Null` would probably require `Null` checks everyone which doesn't seem very "Wolframic."I've gone back-and-forth over whether or not any form of expression validation is required. For experienced users, providing a `PersonQ` function seems sufficient. But for beginners, I think a message would be helpful. Now to just figure out how to emulate the Sin[1,2] behavior!

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean really to emulate `Sin[1,2]` exactly, just that some useful return value is nice (for some definition of useful, which oftentimes does come down to unchanged).

Comment: When I'm designing these kinds of semantic wrappers, I consider several options for what to do for invalid data. Depends on context and expected usage, but here's my short list:

Comment: Coerce invalid instances to valid ones (bviously that might mean messing with the user's data, which is usually not good). Create an alternate wrapper, e.g. `InvalidPerson[...]` (this is nice because you can pattern match on it if users attempt to apply your defined operations on a bad instance). Or change my design so that there basically are no invalid cases (how to do that is highly contextual).

Comment: I guess the above options sort of assume you have a constructor, which is a pattern I often do use for these semantic wrappers.