# Define functions by ‘List’

Tags: function-construction

Let's say I now have a set of variables {x,y,z}，I define functions in terms of x,y, and z，I can do that

```mathematica
f[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z
```

The downside of this definition is that I have to type `x_,y_,z_` repeatedly

If there are 100 variables, I have to do this `f[x1_,x2_,x3_....x100_]:=...`,It's inefficient!

I came up with some ideas,this is my code

```mathematica
vars = {x, y, z}

f[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z

f1 = Function[Evaluate@vars, x + y + z] @@ # &

f1@{1,2,3}

foo[x_] := f @@ (x /. a_Symbol -> a_)

foo@vars
```

But there are flaws,like this:

[image]

so I want to go back to `f[x_,y_,z_]`, using `f[vars]` is obviously not possible,I want to do it in the most intuitive way

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: `F[Thread[Pattern[Evaluate[vars], _]]] := something`

Comment: I agree with you it is not good idea to pass many variables to a function. The less, the better. This is true in any language and not just Mathematica. It can lead to programming errors. Other languages use a *Record* or *struct* to pass many variables in function call in one such record/struct. You can do similar thing in Mathematica. see [struct-equivalent-in-mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/990/struct-equivalent-in-mathematica) for examples.

Comment: @Nasser But my function really has dozens of variables

Comment: `f={x,y,z}|->x+y+z`.

Comment: See if you can change the way you operate on your variables so you can accept a list directly. For instance, in your model case, appropriate variations could be: `g[list_] := Total[list]` or `h[list_] := Plus @@ list`. This would modify the function calls to `g[{x, y, z}]`. It may also have the added advantage that variables in your function call can be grouped by function / logically, alleviating the chance of simple errors and improving readability.

Comment: @MarcoB I'm giving a simple example, just to show。
 you that it's not universal what you're doing

Comment: It's a bit confusing: Do you want `f[x_,y_,z_]` or `f[{x_,y_,z_}]`? The first, which you say want, is not of the form `f[vars]`, which you claim is equivalent. Rather the second is equivalent to `f[vars]`. So which do you want, the first or the second?

Comment: @MichaelE2 for example ,when I get {x,y,z},f[{x,y,z}]=f[x_,y_,z_]

Comment: I still don't understand. Do you mean you want `f[{x,y,z}]` to evaluate to `f[x,y,z]`? Evaluating to `f[x_,y_,z_]` seems wrong, is certainly quite different from `f[{x,y,z}]`. Note `x` and `x_` are different, and `x_` does not depend on `x`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I mean x_ is not x,but，I get some vars，for example {x11,x12,x12...x1n},f[x11_,x12_,x13....x1n]，g[x11_,x12_....,x1n_]，K[x11,x12...x1n,],m[x11_,x12_...x1n_],You know, it's very complicated,I have to type it over and over again.So when I get {x11,x12,...x1n} to f[x11_,x12_,x13_...],g[x11_,x12_...]....

Comment: "I have to type it over and over again": See the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All of your proposals require you to type the full argument list as well as to reference each argument in your function definition. This isn't any reduction in typing for a single function definition. So, I'm inferring that you actually have several functions that all use the same argument list. It's not difficult to define a pattern expression:

```
argPattern1 = Sequence[x_, y_, z_]
```

and then reference it:

```
f1[argPattern1] := x + y + z;
f2[argPattern1] := x y z
(* f1[1, 2, 3] -> 6 *)
```

If you'd rather start with a list of argument names, you could do something like this instead:

```
argNames = {x, y, z};
argPattern2 = Pattern[#, Blank[]] & /@ argNames
```

Usage:

```
g1[argPattern2] := 10 (x + y + z);
g2[argPattern2] := (x + y + z)/10
(* g1[{1, 2, 3}] -> 60 *)
```

Of course, if you started with a list but on occasion need the sequence:

```
argPattern3 = Sequence @@ argPattern2;
h[argPattern3] := 3 x + y + 2 z
(* h[1, 2, 3] -> 11 *)
```

Or, having defined a function already that uses the argument list you want, you could manipulate DownValues:

```
DownValues[k] = ReplacePart[DownValues[f1] /. f1 -> k, {1, 2} -> (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)]
(* k[1, 2, 3] -> 14 *)
```

Manipulating DownValues can be dicey, so be careful. Also make sure that the raw argument names don't have their own definitions--maybe protect them or do the operations in a With or something else along those lines.

Going a completely different route, you could use Slot and just never deal with naming arguments repeatedly:

```
q = Function[#1 + #2^#3]
(* q[1, 2, 3] -> 9 *)
```

Answer (score 4):

While it's unclear which of the following is the desired form, I'll give a general approach and then some specific alternatives:

```
f[x1_, x2_,..., x100_] := ...    (* coordinates as separate arguments *)
f[{x1_, x2_,..., x100_}] := ...  (* coordinates in a single vector *)
```

*First interpretation*

I interpret the exclamation, "It's inefficient!", to mean it's inefficient to type.  Thus we seek an efficient way to edit.  Some code-construction together with copy and paste is helpful.

First construct our arguments.  We can apply our `func` to get code that is ready to edit and add our definition `:= ...`.  We can then apply our next function to `args` and edit the output to construct another function. It seems efficient to me.

```
ClearAll["x*", func]; (* make the workspace ready *)
args = Table[Pattern[Evaluate@ToExpression["x" <> ToString@n], _],
  {n, 100; 3}]
func @@ args
func @ args
(*
  {x1_, x2_, x3_}
  func[x1_, x2_, x3_]
  func[{x1_, x2_, x3_}]
*)
```

Alternatively, depending on the desired form, one can copy the output of `args`, or one can delete the `{` and `}` from the output of `args`. In either case, one gets a cell that can be copied and pasted into a function definition.

So I don't see any inefficiency in constructing the left-hand side of the definition.  The formula for right-hand side, in terms of a hundred variables, might be horrible, but that's beside the point, I guess.

*Second interpretation*

I can see three possible options: We could want the first form (like in @lericr's answer currently accepted), the second form (like in the OP's answer), or both forms to work.  In my early days of using Mathematica, I became irritated that functions $f : {\bf R}^3 \rightarrow {\bf R}$ might equally be considered a function of a single point $(x,y,z)$ or a function of three independent variables $x$, $y$, and $z$.  It makes a difference to Mathematica, but not to mathematicians.  So I got in the habit of doing both, as seen in the examples `func1` and `func2`.  The third, which uses an anonymous `Function`, cannot be polymorphic. The fourth could be made polymorphic in the same way `func1` is; or one could use `Apply@func4`, which operator form of `Apply` did not exist in the early days.

*The setup.*
We set up the variables inside `Hold[]`. We also assign values to the variables to check that our definitions do not leak evaluations.

```
ClearAll["x*", func1, func2, func3, func3vec, func4];
vars = Flatten[
   Hold @@ 
    ToExpression[Table["x" <> ToString@n, {n, 3}], StandardForm, 
     Hold]];
{x1, x2, x3} = Prime@Range@3;
```

**1, 2.**
Note `func1` evaluates the formula when passed the individual coordinate, and has a form for converting `func1[vector]` to `func1[x1, x2, x3]`.  In `func2` it's the reverse.

```
With[{nvars = Length@vars},
  func1[x_List] /; Length@x == nvars := func1 @@ x;
  Activate@Replace[vars, x_ :> Inactive[Pattern][x, _], 1] /. 
   Hold[v__] :>
    (func1[v] := x1 + x2 + x3);
  ];

func2[x_List] := x . {1, 1, 1}; (* math. short-cut :) *)
func2[x___] := func2[{x}];
```

**3.**
An anonymous function can't be polymorphic, so different versions are given for each form.  One could have `func3vec` call `func3` conditionally, but that hardly seems a solution anyone would prefer.

```
vars /. Hold[v__] :>
  (func3 = Function[{v}, x1 + x2 + x3])

(*  Function[{x1, x2, x3}, x1 + x2 + x3]  *)

vars /. Hold[v__] :>
  (func3vec =
    Block[{v},
      {v} = #;
      x1 + x2 + x3] &)

(*  Block[{x1, x2, x3}, {x1, x2, x3} = #1; x1 + x2 + x3] &  *)
```

**4.**
If one can construct the body of the function `expr` programmatically, then `func4` shows a way to make it into a function.  The function `func4` can be overloaded to handle a vector argument in the same was that `func1` was.

```
expr = vars /. Hold[v__] :> Block[{v}, (* make held expression *)
     x1 + x2 + x3 // Hold[#] &];       (* for body of func4 *)
{Activate@Replace[vars, x_ :> Inactive[Pattern][x, _], 1],
   expr} /.
 {Hold[v__], Hold[e_]} :> (func4[v] := e);
```

*Testing.*  Since `func3` and `func4` don't have a vector form, they can be applied to a vector argument with the operator form `Apply@f`.

```
Through[{func1, func2, Apply@func3, Apply@func4}[Table[x[n], {n, 3}]]]
(*
{x[1] + x[2] + x[3],
 x[1] + x[2] + x[3],
 x[1] + x[2] + x[3], 
 x[1] + x[2] + x[3]}
*)

Through[{func1, func2, func3, func4}[x[1], x[2], x[3]]]
(* <same as above> *)

func3vec@Table[x[n], {n, 3}] (* for completeness *)
(*  x[1] + x[2] + x[3]  *)
```