# How to determine three last bindings made to a variable when evaluating an expression?

Tags: algorithm

How can I create a list of bindings made to a certain variable when evaluating an expression? I want to determine three  bindings made.

Comment: `Trace[expr,i=_]`

Comment: Make a class that represents the variable (as say with Java's Integer class), with private array that keeps track of all assignments/time stamp/counters, etc.. all hidden inside the class, Supply a set[] and get[] methods to the clients of your variable to use on the variable once it is instantiated. Making such Class in M is very easy. Make a Module, and inside the Module create the local variables and private methods. see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/586/how-can-you-give-a-module-a-context-and-have-its-local-variables-and-modules-bel for one example.